# range of primitive numerics - double

Tags: java

I am learning about the range of primitive types and I have question about type `double`.

If we know that `double` has 8 bytes (64 bits) - why is it impossible to determine minimum and maximum range of `double`?

`long` has 8 bytes as well but we can determine minimum and maximum.

Comment: Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY? Or Double.MAX_VALUE?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650505/what-is-the-inclusive-range-of-float-and-double-in-java

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.3

Comment: There is a minimum/maximum, they're just not necessarily named as intuitively as one might like. Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3884793/minimum-values-and-double-min-value-in-java

Comment: thats "floating" point variable. Floating not stationary.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure this is the maximum and minimum range:

> MAX_VALUE
>             A constant holding the largest positive finite value of type double, (2-2<sup>-52</sup>)·2<sup>1023</sup>.
>
> MIN_VALUE
>             A constant holding the smallest positive nonzero value of type double, 2<sup>-1074</sup>.

according to the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html) both of these functions return a primitive double.

Comment: These are with a very poor minimum step.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik hmm?

Comment: I mean when value is big, the minimum value that can be added/subtracted is big too.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't aware that we wouldn't determine the minimum and maximum range of double. A quick google search shows:

Double covers a range from 4.94065645841246544e-324d to 1.79769313486231570e+308d (positive or negative).

If you look at this question though, you can find out more information: [What is the inclusive range of float and double in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650505/what-is-the-inclusive-range-of-float-and-double-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Doubles are not stored the same way longs or ints are stored.

It is stored similar to scientific notation.

That is, a certain number of significant figures and a power.

Edit, the answer above indicates that there is a min and max. However, this is due to a limit on how high the power component of the double can be (i.e. it can only take up so many bits).

Comment: i think you are confusing this with the Big* classes such as BigInteger.

Comment: There must be a maximal number, even if you are using all the atoms in the universe.

Comment: Please see: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.3. I have edited my answer to reflect your input.