# How to read a number using minimal-json

Tags: java, json, minimal-json

I am using [minimal-json](https://github.com/ralfstx/minimal-json) to parse a JSON stream in Java. This framework has a number of methods to read a number form the stream: `asInt()`, `asLong()`, `asFloat()`, and `asDouble()`. Assuming that I don't know what is the numerical type of the element, what method gives me the best accuracy? I'm asking this because I fear that reading all elements using `asDouble()` can cause loss of information. Is this a wrong assumption?

Comment: Why do you think double will  cause loss of information?

Comment: @hellboy Check the answers of [this[(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650505/what-is-the-inclusive-range-of-float-and-double-in-java) question to understand my fear.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you know that the numbers aren't going to be massive, I would use a float because its a smaller memory size. the last response on this stackoverflow question is the reason I would say use float. But if you aren't certain use a double:
[float and double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650505/what-is-the-inclusive-range-of-float-and-double-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

If a 64-bit long is written as an integer, and is greater than 2**53 (IEEE double has a 52-bit mantissa), then reading it as a double will lose precision.

One could make an argument, though, that storing such a number in JSON is the writer's error, because Javascript does not have 64-bit integers, only doubles.