# JSF f:convertNumber round up currency

Tags: jsf, double, rounding, money-format

is it possible to use f:convertNumber to round up?  I checked [the api here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/1.1_01/docs/tlddocs/f/convertNumber.html) and it didn't mention anything about rounding.  If not, what is the next best thing to convert a double to a $ value while rounding it up?

```
<f:convertNumber maxFractionDigits="2" groupingUsed="true" currencySymbol="$" maxIntegerDigits="7" type="currency" />
```

Ex: $1.104999 should become $1.11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for my specific case.  But will it have any other edge cases that will break?

First, round it in my java class:

```
private double roundCost(double cost) {
    return (Math.ceil(cost*100))/100;
}
```

Then past that to my f:convertNumber.

I'm open to other suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You really shouldn't be using a primitive `double` in Java when dealing with exact numbers such as monetary amounts; rather, use `java.lang.BigDecimal` or some custom Money type; for an explanation why, see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413448/double-vs-bigdecimal).

`BigDecimal` has support for several rounding modes; the one you are looking for is probably [`java.math.RoundingMode.UP`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html#UP).

As for the question on how to combine this with a f:convertNumber, I'm looking into that myself currently.

Answer (score 0):

One can add 0,005 (in your case) before using the default-rounding-mechanism.