# Which data type to use for manipulating currency

Tags: java, currency

I am trying to decide which data type shall i use for a financial application.

I have read that `Double` or `BigDecimal` should be used. And i am confused between them. 
Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You almost certainly don't want to use floating-point types (`double`, `float`, `Double`, `Float`) to handle monetary amounts, especially if you will be performing computations on them. The main reason for this is that there are many simple-looking numbers that cannot be represented exactly as a `double` et al. One such number is `0.1`.

`BigDecimal` is therefore a much better choice for this use case.

Answer (score 2):

Use BigDecimal, it's a lot better than Double for financial stuff. See here the accepted answer for a similar question:
[Double vs. BigDecimal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413448/double-vs-bigdecimal)

Answer (score 2):

BigDecimal isn't only best choice, BigDecimal is designed for such case.

Answer (score 2):

For most applications, a simple `long` will do: when representing cents, this will handle amounts up to 10^17 {Dollars, Euros, whatever}.