# Is overflow over a summation applicable to double precision floating data types?

Tags: java, sum, double, overflow, addition

If we want to sum over a big range of numbers the fact that the data type used is a floating point double precision does it make the running sum less susceptible to overflow?
Should we still some explicitly write code to detect it and stop the summation?

Comment: what language is this? It doesn't matter the data type used; if you sum over enough numbers it will overflow unless you use a library to handle it for you

Comment: I originally though this question is language agnostic but I added `Java` since what I normally use

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413448/double-vs-bigdecimal

Comment: double covers a range from 4.94065645841246544e-324d to 1.79769313486231570e+308d (positive or negative). This is pretty much, however the precesion is only about 17 decimals. This means long before the overflow your sum will be only a rough estimation with hundreds zero digits at the end. So dealing with big numbers requires BigInteger or BigDecimal if more than an esitmation is needed.