# Printing Java doubles to System.out in Java

Tags: java, double

This code isn't working as I thought it would.

```
a=-1;   
b=0.1;   
for(i=0;i<=20;i++){  
    System.out.println(i + ". x= " + a);   
    a=a+b;   
}
```

On the console I should see:

```
0. x= -1.0  
1. x= -0.9  
2. x= -0.8  
3. x= -0.7  
4. x= -0.6  
5. x= -0.5  
6. x= -0.4  
7. x= -0.3
```

...etc

But this is what happens:

```
0. x= -1.0  
1. x= -0.9  
2. x= -0.8  
3. x= -0.7000000000000001  
4. x= -0.6000000000000001  
5. x= -0.5000000000000001  
6. x= -0.40000000000000013  
7. x= -0.30000000000000016  
8. x= -0.20000000000000015  
9. x= -0.10000000000000014  
10. x= -1.3877787807814457E-16  
11. x= 0.09999999999999987  
12. x= 0.19999999999999987  
13. x= 0.2999999999999999  
14. x= 0.3999999999999999  
15. x= 0.4999999999999999  
16. x= 0.5999999999999999  
17. x= 0.6999999999999998  
18. x= 0.7999999999999998  
19. x= 0.8999999999999998  
20. x= 0.9999999999999998
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You didn't specify the type of a and b in your code sample. Can you add that?

Comment: You're not doing anything wrong. It's just that decimals can not be perfectly represented by binary, so there is a little bit of difference between the expected value and the real value being stored.

Comment: This is a duplicate of many questions. Let's find a good candidate duplicate and close this.

Comment: You might find http://floating-point-gui.de/ helpful.

Comment: You asked a question and provided all the details. Few people do that on their first questions, even if it is a duplicate. +1

Comment: I have also given a +1 following appreciation of @SotiriosDelimanolis and then immediately closed your question :P

Answer (score 4):

What you have here is **floating point inaccuracy**. Because `double`s have limited precision they cannot precisely represent all decimal numbers. In particular `0.1` is a recurring binary so *all* finite length binary representations will be inaccurate. This means the computer cannot store the numbers you're using exactly.

You can fix your output by formatting it (e.g. `System.out.format("%d. x=%.1f", i, a);`) or you can fix your numbers by using `BigDecimal` instead of `double`. Alternatively you could reduce the scale of the problem by calculating `a` each time rather than accumulating (and adding an incremental error each time), e.g. `a = i/10.0`. It depends on what you are trying to achieve.

The important "take home message" is that doubles cannot be relied on to give complete accurate answers and you should expect small errors in floating point arithmetic.

Comment: A very good explanation which gives both the reason and solutions for two different scenarios!

Answer (score 2):

When you need precision: use `BigDecimal` instead of `double`.

Refer to this question for more details: [Double vs. BigDecimal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413448/double-vs-bigdecimal)

edit: if you don't need precision; you're ok with formatting the output..

Comment: No. He just needs to format his output. These aren't financial or rocket engineering equations, but simple floating point calculations. Using a double with formatted output will do just fine.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: How do we know? Our asker doesn't tell us what the downstream application of this is.

Answer (score 2):

Try formatting your output:

```
for(i=0;i<=20;i++){  
    System.out.format("%d. x=%.1f", i, a);   
    a=a+b;   
}
```

For more on formatting output, see the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html)

Answer (score 1):

A personal favorite of mine is to use `System.out.printf()`

Like it's C counterpart you define the type of the variables your going to pass to it then just fling it an something of that type. For example
`System.out.printf("%.1f", yourDouble);`

Should do the trick.

Resources:
[Printf cheat sheet](http://www.cs.gsu.edu/csc2010/f13/assignments/h4/printf.pdf)

Comment: For the record, `System.out.printf` and `System.out.format` are exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using ints for each of those objects. Instead when you go to display them call this method first :

```
public static double round(double value, int places) {
    if (places < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();

    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(value);
    bd = bd.setScale(places, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
    return bd.doubleValue();
}
```

Or use the correct type of object instead of ints...

Answer (score 0):

use String.format or just pain decimal formatting syntax in system.out.println and you should see what you want.
float point arithmetic is internally represented in a different way. So a simple print of such values wont always give you want you need interms of on screen view format.