# What is the most exact Java type to describe a Number

Tags: java, types, numbers

Assuming that performance is not an issue, and knowing that I only want to use **ONE** type for all the numbers I have in my program, which type will be the correct one to use? I think that `BigDecimal` is probably the best option, but I'm not sure of this.

Comment: I am afraid this is a primarily opinion based question, and probably too broad to answer. BigDecimal is robust enough to handle almost anything your likely to throw at it, but we have no idea what your application does or needs to do.

Comment: you answeared yourself - BigDecimal

Comment: Maybe you functions should be generic enough to work with any kind of number instead of working with "the" number type that doesn't exist. BigDecimal can't even represent 1/3 correctly, let alone pi, sqrt(-1), a quaternion or most surreal numbers.

Comment: Why do you need only **one** type for representing numbers?

Comment: String. Can represent everything.   :-)

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose that's very hardcore, don't you think? +1

Comment: Write the code to accept `java.lang.Number` as input. Then the caller who knows the number can choose the optimal number type for the value, which might be `BigDecimal` but doesn’t have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. If you only want to use **one** type (which excludes `BigInteger` ),
you should use `BigDecimal`.

Here is an explanation : [The need of BigDecimal](http://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/the_need_for_bigdecimal)

And you can also check this answer: [Double vs. BigDecimal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413448/double-vs-bigdecimal)

Answer (score 7):

It depends on how you want to use the numbers.

If you are unlikely to need floating point and the numbers aren't going to get too big use `int` as the most efficient use of the CPU.

If the numbers might get too big for `int` use `long`. Uses twice the memory but still cpu efficient.

If too big for `long` use `BigInteger`. Uses the optimum number of bytes for the number. Breaks when number > about 2^65535 so works for most scenarios. Slower than `int` or `long` but still seriously fast.

If too big for `BigInteger` you're on your own. Perhaps one day ...

If you need float maths `float` or `double` are good so long as you are working in their range.

For big float maths or a more predictable calculation than `double` or `float`, use `BigDecimal`. Ha sits limitations like `BigInteger` but it is rare to be bitten by them.

Beyond that if you are working solely in rationals then you may find a rational number class useful and more accurate than `BigDecimal`. [This](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/32class/Rational.java.html) looks ok.

If you are likely to move into irrational territory you may find some of the continued-fractions classes of use. [Here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/util/ContinuedFraction.html) is an example.