# High Charts donut chart percentages adding to 100.1%

Tags: javascript, math, highcharts

I created a donut chart using `High Charts` as shown below. My problem is that the subsets are totaling to 100.1%. I am not `rounding` and my numbers are all of type `double`s. Does anyone have an idea as to where my math could go wrong to get this ever-so-slight problem?

7.7 + 7.0 + 15.3 + 70.1 = 100.1

**Chart**

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide a bit more of "surrounding" information? Some more code?

Comment: @sshashank124 What kind of information are you looking for? - I would be glad to include it. The amount of code I use to generate this chart is far too much to post. I am mainly looking for 'possible' problems or a push in the right direction.

Comment: Where is the chart getting its values from? How are you creating it? What data types are you using for your numbers?

Comment: @sshashank124 In my question I include data types are all `double`, The chart is getting its values from a JSON object I created using queries. The data is used once before and generates another donut chart correctly (which is why I am confused about this one).

Comment: What are the data values you are using for this chart?

Comment: @JordanD. Ok so firstly, the sum is 100.1 not 101.1 but that's not important. Secondly, I doubt your High Charts module is messing up your data so it must be what you are passing in. I recommend checking what you are passing in by printing it to the html screen by document or something like that.

Comment: @sshashank124 sorry for the silly algebra error, I fixed it. After a few console logs it seems doubles are rounding to 1 decimal places.

Comment: @JordanD, nice! You should post your solution as an answer so that others in the future may refer to it.

Comment: @sshashank124 After I find a way to truncate the double instead of rounding it I will post my answer.

Comment: @JordanD, An easy way of truncating a double is to `round(num-1)`. This gives the same effect as truncation. The method I gave is just pseudocode not actual code

Comment: Surely the values presented in those labels are rounded. If not, you have the most unusually precise data I've ever seen, to have only 1 decimal place for every single percentage...

Answer (score 4):

It's just caused by rounding done in formatter. Let's consider this example: http://jsfiddle.net/MkuMS/

Sum is: `74.5+14.1+10.3+1.2 = 100.1`

Now, let's remove rounding from `dataLabels.format`: http://jsfiddle.net/MkuMS/1/

Sum is: `74.50331125827813+14.072847682119205+10.264900662251655+1.1589403973509933 = 100`

Now, it's up to you, or you are going to display with rounding error, or full info in labels (which looks.. bad) or create your own `dataLabels.formatter`.

But you will still encounter issue with non rounding values: http://jsfiddle.net/MkuMS/3/

Sum is: `33.3+33.3+33.3 = 99.9`

Answer (score 0):

It may be because of the `double` type. It's not precise enough in some cases. Try using `BigDecimal` instead.

More info: [Double vs. BigDecimal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413448/double-vs-bigdecimal)