# How to force console to output larger numbers

Tags: java, infinity

I am writing a recursive formula and require values when the function has run hundreds of times. At near the 450th - 500th run, the console outputs `infinity`.

Is it possible to force Java to output a larger value but in scientific notation?

Recursion:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
        System.out.println(Math.pow(3 + 2 * Math.sqrt(2), i)
                + Math.pow(3 - 2 * Math.sqrt(2), i));
    }
}
```

Output at roughly 450th run:

```
2.4705373096084562E302
1.4399346668019402E303
8.392554269850795E303
4.891539095230283E304
2.8509979144396616E305
1.661683357711494E306
9.685000354824998E306
5.644831877123849E307
Infinity
Infinity
Infinity
Infinity
Infinity
Infinity
Infinity
Infinity
Infinity
```

**Edit**

I have used `BigDecimal`, as recommended.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
        BigDecimal n = new BigDecimal(Math.pow(3 + 2 * Math.sqrt(2), i)
                + Math.pow(3 - 2 * Math.sqrt(2), i));
        System.out.println(n);
    }
```

However, now the console spits out :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: Infinite or NaN
at java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(BigDecimal.java:808)
at mathC.Recursion2.main(Recursion2.java:9)
```

I have read that `BigDecimal` should be able to store a value that is roughly 8Gb of memory. Since my laptop contains 16Gb of 1600MHz memory, why is this happening? Is this number really 8Gb of memory?

The number before the error is (SO won't let me format this):

`56448318771238491045438986070422562722375814412748377586799357549587081845130965398544956161588871436829847442988862310610370686259432485701530038671444090445069088383193741454463060427351807692569019541559990842957532377423388218307948475268885262237809144041880563122951075397138587894276020263963236237312`

Comment: FYI, this is to study the behaviour of the recursive function in the code sample.

Comment: You may want to look at Java's BigDecimal: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html

Comment: That is not a recursive method; `main` doesn't call itself.

Comment: @rgettman yea you're right, this is not a method.. this is a `for-loop` running a function..@merlin okay I will check that out. Thanks.

Comment: You're now just taking the `double` result, which has already overflowed, and converting it to a `BigDecimal`. You need to do the whole computation with `BigDecimal` to avoid the overflow.

Comment: I'd recommend looking again at the recursive form (`BigInteger` may help). Failing that: as you know, the result is always integral as the square root terms cancel out. Perhaps think about performing the power computations symbolically, simplifying as you go.

Comment: @AlanStokes My apologies, I have deleted my previous comment as `Real` is not included in the default java libraries. I will try your recommendation though. If not, then I guess I will be stuck analyzing only 400 numbers and not 500 :(

Comment: Another alternative would be to compute the logarithm of the final answer - which will easily fit in a `double`. Depends what analysis you want to do, of course.

Comment: @AlanStokes The analysis actually requires a large amount of precision. I am essentially seeing how close this formula gets to an integer as `i` increases (b.c. 3+2(sqrt(2)) is irrational). I have figured it out using `BigDecimal` though. thanks.

Comment: The answer is always exactly an integer, isn't it? The even terms of sqrt(2) are integral and the odd terms cancel out. (You can represent the values as an integer/BigInteger plus an integer multiple of sqrt(2), and then compute the results exactly.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a look at [BigDecimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413448/double-vs-bigdecimal).

(That doesn't look very recursive, as Fibonacci algorithms go.)

Comment: This is recursive.. the function is in its closed form.

Comment: Where "closed" means non-recursive ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Once the values get large enough, they exceed the maximum value that a `double` can store: [`Double.MAX_VALUE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.lang.Double.MAX_VALUE), or `1.7976931348623157E308`.  When such an operation exceeds this maximum value, then the `double` value `Infinity` results.

This is specified by the [JLS, Section 15.18.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.2):

> If the magnitude of the sum is too large to represent, we say the operation overflows; the result is then an infinity of appropriate sign.

(Other binary arithmetic operators have their own JLS Section, and they say the same thing.)

To get a bigger range, use a [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) to store results with arbitrary precision.

Comment: Perfect theoretical explanation. Here's a follow up link: [floating point standard](http://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_double-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary64)

Comment: Okay, i have implemented `BigDecimal` as recommended. However, an error now comes up, please see latest edit on question.

Comment: It looks like your intermediate result is equal to your last scientific notation number - `5.644831877123849E307`.  You're still performing `double` arithmetic before the value gets passed to a `BigDecimal`.  Try performing all arithmetic operations using values that are already `BigDecimal`s, with `add`, `multiply`, and `subtract`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't know what the goal of the program is, but ***if*** you ***just*** want it to print it (instead of re-using it in another operaton), why not using the International System for quick notation? That way, you only have to create an `if` statement with the desired range.

(Here's a link to a table with the values :
http://ronblond.com/MathGlossary/Division03/International%20System%20of%20Units/PrefixChart.gif)

Not only it solves that issue (once again, if you merely want the output, and a ***non-exact*** one), but it's also easier on the eye.

---//--- Example (Edit) ---//---

Let's take 2222, thus, 1,10 and 1k. If on a cicle you divide it by a multiple of 10, you can in theory easily convert it. Let's see:

```
      // For cicle here with an increasing i. n is how many times you've divided
     if (i>999 && i<10000){    // if you have i=2222

    i=(i/(n*10));   // in this case, n=100 , thus the  integer i = 2
    System.out.println(i + "k");  // 2222 is aproximatly 2k

    }
```

Although, this would only work if you could actually create a way to stop the loop. Something that has only came up to me now.

Comment: Internation System..?

Comment: If you can't represent the answer, there's no way to print it.

Comment: Even though you can't represent it, you can (since the code is always increasing) divide it by a variable (which would be a multiple of 10), thus, once you reach a certain limit, the variable would be smaller (thus you can represent it)

Comment: @Alan Stokes, take a look at the awnser (I added an example), it solves the problem you created, although it creates a new one, which would render this cicle infinite.

Comment: @user3126359 I understand you now. So basically, when the answer becomes too large, convert it to a larger unit (thus making the number of digits smaller). Nice. Although I would lose precision which is needed in this case.

Comment: Yes, that would be a an issue, but, should you only need a rounded up number, that it would work =)