# How can I only show three digists of the double value

Tags: java

I have double values like 0.0345333 or 1.0897777 and I want to convert them to 0.034 and 1.089 in Java?

How can I do it?

I want to convert the values, not print them since I need it for calculation.

I find the following way but I am looking for simple way.
`double score=(tff* idf);
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
p.score=Double.parseDouble(df.format(score));`

Comment: Do you want to truncate or round?

Comment: @RichardTingle Obviously truncate from examples

Comment: @m0skit0 I did see those, never a bad thing to ask however. Its so easy to not notice

Comment: This is just for outputting or for using this values for other calculations?

Comment: @RichardTingle Then let's ask if he's sure if it's Java, or sure if it's a programming language he's talking about... ;)

Comment: @m0skit0 *sigh* you'll notice that a whole load of answers and duplicate votes assuming rounding rather than truncating. I'm not sure why you think its so terrible me encouraging making the distiction clear

Comment: You need to use the `BigDecimal`. Have a look at thia - [Double vs. BigDecimal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413448/double-vs-bigdecimal).

Comment: I wrote the following code but I want easeir way. double score=(tff* idf);
          DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
          p.score=Double.parseDouble(df.format(score));

Comment: It is for calculation

Comment: If it's for calculation then you need to use the `BigDecimal`. You can achieve that with `double`. `BigDecimal` is like the WYSIWYG version of `double`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will truncate value to 3 decimal places:

```
value = ((int)(value*1000))/1000.0;
```

This will round to 3 decimal places:

```
value = (double)Math.round(value*1000)/1000;
```

For example:

```
double d1 = 0.0345333;
d1 = (double)Math.round(d1*1000)/1000;
System.out.println(d1); // 0.035

double d2 = 0.0345333;
d2 = ((int)(d2 *1000))/1000.0;
System.out.println(d2); // 0.034
```

Comment: It is not work it changes value to 0 and 1 respectivley

Comment: If the value is an integer it won't work, if it's a double it will.

Comment: The value are double but it is not work for me

Comment: I think `Math.round` returns a `long` so you want to be dividing by `1000.0`.

Comment: @2rs2ts That's why I casted to double.

Comment: @AnubianNoob ah, sorry, I thought the case would apply after the division. I tried it on ideone and it worked (although it gave me `0.035`.)

Comment: This rounds, not truncates, to 3 decimal places `value = Math.round(value*1000)/1000.0;`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to display the result use.

```
String.format("%1$,.3f", myDouble);
```

But if you need to truncate the numbers you could use:

```
double number = 1.0897777;
double result = ((int)(number*1000))/1000d;//1.089
```

Comment: This prints the value, it doesn't convert it.

Comment: Is there a way I only work with double not string.

Comment: @AnubianNoob I see you are quite quick at giving minuses... Well, thanks for that... i guess.

Comment: @Gogutz What? Also this now answers the question.

Comment: The second answer you give is the best answer to the question asked--I don't think it's a great solution because of the way doubles work which is why Scale is not in the Double class but is in the BigDecimal class.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `BigDecimal`

```
BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal(1.0897777);
value = value.setScale(3, RoundingMode.DOWN);
```

Comment: If you are doing "Rounding" type calculations and want to continue tow work with the results rather than just display them, then this is almost ceratinly the best answer.  A double or float will almost always get jacked up during such a rounding operation (rounding 1.0897777 back into a double will end up as 1.089000001 or something).