# BigDecimal with decimates value?

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I'm trying divide a value using BigDecimal, when this value is a decimates BigDecimal round this value and I wont to do that. I need the decimates value are shown. For example, if I do divide `10 / 3 = 3.33333`, I need shown `3.33` but does show `3.00`

How could I do this ?

```
//Result-> 10 / 2 = 3,3333333

BigDecimal result = new BigDecimal(0);
BigDecimal v1 = new BigDecimal(10);
BigDecimal v2 = new BigDecimal(3);
result = v1.divide(v2, BigDecimal.ROUND_UP);

//output = 3
//I need output = 3.33
```

Comment: If you want the decimals, why have you added BigDecimal.ROUND_UP to your divide call???

Comment: The output I get when I run this (as of this writing) is `4`.

Comment: v1.divide(v2*100, Big...)/100 ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Double vs. BigDecimal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413448/double-vs-bigdecimal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to *`compile`* and `run` this java class, *it works as you wish*:

```
import java.math.*;
class decimal {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
BigDecimal result = new BigDecimal(0);
BigDecimal v1 = new BigDecimal(10);
BigDecimal v2 = new BigDecimal(3);
result = v1.divide(v2,2,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
System.out.println(result);
}
}
```

output : `3.33`

you want two decimal digits this is why I set `scale=2`

Answer (score 2):

The *scale* of `BigDecimal`s that were initialized with `int`s is `0`, meaning that rounding operations round to unity.  With your example, the division rounds *up* to `4`.

Set the scale of the first `BigDecimal` to `2`, which be retained through the division.  Also set the rounding mode to "down".

```
BigDecimal v1 = new BigDecimal(10).setScale(2);
BigDecimal v2 = new BigDecimal(3);
result = v1.divide(v2, BigDecimal.ROUND_DOWN);
```

Printing `results` now yields an output of `3.33`.

You could have also used the `RoundingMode` enum as a drop-in replacement for the rounding constants.  Additionally, you could have used `ROUND_HALF_DOWN`, `ROUND_HALF_UP`, or `ROUND_HALF_EVEN` (or their `RoundingMode` equivalents).

You could use a string with the appropriate number of decimal digits to set the scale implicitly.

```
BigDecimal v1 = new BigDecimal("10.00");  // scale of 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add scale to BigDecimal, like this:

```
public class User {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BigDecimal result = new BigDecimal(0);
        BigDecimal v1 = new BigDecimal(10).setScale(2);
        BigDecimal v2 = new BigDecimal(3);
        result = v1.divide(v2, BigDecimal.ROUND_DOWN);

        System.out.println(result);

    }
}
```