# How to use ResultSet of java to get precise value of float of mysql

Tags: java, mysql, resultset, floating-accuracy

Is it possible in Java, I use `ResultSet`, to get the precise value of `float` of `mysql`?

In my database of mysql, I have some values of `float` which are very long(for example, 123456789, more than 7 digits), I know if I use `select round(float_value_column,0)` I can get the precise value. But if I use `ResultSet.GetFloat` of java, I can get only the rounded value(123457000, just like in mysql I made `select float_value_column`).

May I ask, if I use `ResultSet.GetDouble`, may I get the precise value? or may I do like `ResultSet.GetFloat(round(float_value_column,0))`?

Thank you very much

Comment: What about `BigDecimal`?

Comment: hi, alkis, thank you very much for your reply. what do you mean BigDecimal, you mean in Java or in Mysql? thanks

Comment: @martinwang1985: have you tried to call `ResultSet.getDouble`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the below code

```
ResultSet rs = .....

    BigDecimal myValue = rs.getBigDecimal("Column Name");
            float myFloatValue = myValue.floatValue();
```

More about [BigDecimal here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html).

You can have a look at this [SOW post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413448/double-vs-bigdecimal) as well.