# Precision of double when dealing with whole numbers? Datatype to represent whole numbers of money?

Tags: java

I'm trying to represent money with a datatype in Java. There's a condition though: the ***money will always be a whole number*** (eg. $500, $10000000). The choices I thought of are:

**Double**: Faster than the other choices available. That said, will there be a [loss of precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413448/double-vs-bigdecimal)? Also, is a double enough to represent any amount of money? I mean, money can get pretty large, so is a double enough to store all such values?

**BigInteger**: The upside here is that there's no limit as such, and obviously no loss of precision. That said, the speed of computations could take a hit.

Which one should I use?

EDIT: This is not a duplicate and is different in that I need to use ***only whole numbers*** for money, which brings the question of precision and suitability!

Comment: None of the above. Use `BigDecimal`. Don't even consider floating-point, ever in your career. I've seen software companies lose lots of money due to rework by getting this wrong.

Comment: @EJP Why not BigInteger?

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `double`. As you are aware, floating point calculations can result in a loss of precision.

`BigInteger` would work, but it is a reference type which makes it more awkward to use.

Use `long`. The maximum value is `9223372036854775807` which is likely to be large enough for practical purposes.

Comment: Only just large enough. Cobol has 18 decimal digits of visible precision, plus enough extra for correct rounding. And fractions, which `long` doesn't have. And scaling. `BigDecimal` has all this.

Comment: @EJP The OP only required integers, so assuming `Long.MAX_VALUE` is big enough for their needs, this is the best solution in terms of convenience and performance for them. However I wouldn't normally recommend `long` for calculations involving money.

Comment: @PaulBoddington why not long, though?