# Java DecimalFormat HALF_UP rounding error

Tags: java, rounding, bigdecimal

I'm using the DecimalFormat with HALF_UP rounding mode and I have an escenery where is not working correctly and I don't know why.

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
float tmp = (float) (0.5 * 1.05);
df.format(tmp);
float mul = Float.parseFloat(df.format(tmp));
```

The `mul` variable value I hope have 0.53 value and I received 0.52 value.

I'm using the Java 1.8.0_131.

**SOLVED FINAL CODE**

```
BigDecimal mul = new BigDecimal(0.5).multiply(new igDecimal(1.05));
mul = mul.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
System.out.println(mul);
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but I need rounding as HALF_UP must works "Rounding mode to round towards "nearest neighbor" unless both neighbors are equidistant, in which case round up." [Oracle Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html)

Comment: `float` and `double` cannot store values precisely... See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3413448/4899193

Comment: this works `System.out.println(df.format(0.5 * 1.05));` - of course doubles

Comment: I do not think.... Try printing out `tmp`, like `System.out.println(""+tmp);`

Comment: As per the answer below, `double` is sufficient, while `float` is not. And `tmp` is declare as `float`....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**You are using the `float` datatype.**

This datatype is not able to precisely hold the value `0.525`. See this code for making it clear:

```
float value = (float) (0.5 * 1.05);
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.########################");
System.out.println(df.format(value));
```

This prints out:

> 0.5249999761581421

Rounding such a value with the mode `RoundingMode.HALF_UP` will *correctly* yield `0.52`.

The `double` value *seems* to be able to precisely store the value `0.525`:

```
double value = 0.5 * 1.05;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.########################");
System.out.println(df.format(value));
```

This will print the expected value:

> 0.525

Rounding that value with the mode `RoundingMode.HALF_UP` will now yield `0.53`!

**Caution: Even the `double` datatype does not store the value precisely!**

Look at @MarkDickinson's comment. The stored value is `0.52500000000000002220446049250313080847263336181640625` which happens to be larger than `0.525` and only rounds by accident to the expected value.

**So what to do?**

The data types `float` and `double` are binary-based, whereas we humans tend to think decimal-based when dealing with numbers. Read the article ["What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic"](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) for much more information.

The solution is to use a decimal-based data type, which exists in `BigDecimal`.

Comment: This answer is misleading; a `double` is _not_ able to store the value `0.525` precisely: it stores `0.52500000000000002220446049250313080847263336181640625` instead. Because that value just _happens_ to be above `0.525`, it rounds upwards. Try with `0.7 * 1.05` and you'll see it rounding down instead of up. If the OP cares about correct rounding of _decimal_ halfway cases, they need to be using a decimal-based numeric type.

Comment: Thank you for your quickly answer, but my rounding continue with something wrong:
    `double tmp = 0.5 * 1.05;
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
    df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    System.out.println(df.format(tmp));`
Thats returns 1.52

Comment: @MarkDickinson Thanks for your finding. I somehow missed it. Changed my answer.