# How to implement the equals/hashCode methods for classes that contain double fields

Tags: java

I am overriding equals and hashCode in a class that includes double fields. My first approach was to use the epsilon test in the equals method, and Double.hashCode( double ) in hashCode, but that can result in equal objects having different hash codes; here is a simplified example:

```
public class DoubleHashTest2
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        double  base1   = .9;
        double  base2   = .7;
        Test    test1   = new Test( base1 - .1 );
        Test    test2   = new Test( base2 + .1 );

        System.out.println( test1.equals( test2 ) );
        System.out.println( test1.hashCode() );
        System.out.println( test2.hashCode() );
    }

    private static class Test
    {
        private double  dnum1;

        public Test( double dnum1 )
        {
            this.dnum1 = dnum1;
        }

        public boolean equals( Test other )
        {
            final double    epsilon = .0001;
            boolean         result  = false;
            if ( this == other )
                result = true;
            else if ( other == null )
                result = false;
            else
                result  = Math.abs( this.dnum1 - other.dnum1 ) < epsilon;
            return result;
        }

        public int hashCode()
        {
            int hash    = Double.hashCode( dnum1 );
            return hash;
        }
    }
}
```

I've thought of several solutions, including converting to BigDecimal, but I'm not really happy with any of them. I finally settled on rounding:

```
public boolean equals( Test other )
{
    boolean         result  = false;
    if ( this == other )
        result = true;
    else if ( other == null )
        result = false;
    else
    {
        double  test1   = round( dnum1 );
        double  test2   = round( other.dnum1 );
        result  = test1 == test2;
    }
    return result;
}

public int hashCode()
{
    double  temp    = round( dnum1 );
    int hash    = Double.hashCode( temp );
    return hash;
}

private double round( double dnum )
{
    // tests for NaN and +/-infinity omitted for brevity
    final int       places      = 4;
    final double    round_const = Math.pow( 10, places );
    double result   = ((int)(dnum * round_const + .5)) / round_const;
    return result;
}
```

But choosing a good rounding algorithm is difficult, and this seems kind of expensive. I looked at similar classes, such as Point2D.Double, but equals in this class fails, for example, when comparing .8 and 0.7999999999999999.

Is there a recommended way for dealing with this issue?

Comment: Yes: give up on double equality; stop using equals and hashCode if you want matches that aren't 100% exactly matching.  Any attempt to make that work is doomed.

Comment: Your method definition `equals(Test)`  is incorrect. Equals must be overridden from `Object` as `equals(Object)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
public static boolean equals( double param1, double param2 )
{
    final double    epsilon  = 1e-10;
    
    // accounts for 0, NaN, +/-INFINITY
    boolean result  = param1 == param2;
    if ( !result )
    {
        double quot = param1 / param2;
        result = quot > 0 && (1 - quot) < epsilon;
    }
    
    return result;
}
```

To demonstrate:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    double dvar1 = 0.7 + 0.1;
    double dvar2 = 0.9 - 0.1;
    System.out.println( dvar1 == dvar2 ); // expect false
    System.out.println( equals( dvar1, dvar2 ) ); // expect true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Answering the main question

You don't need any custom rounding, as `Double` class has [`doubleToLongBits()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#doubleToLongBits-double-) method, which simply converts `double` to `long` (both of them are 64-bit values).

Also, for your `equals()` method, you can compare two `double` values with [`Double#compare()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#compare-double-double-).

Possible `equals()` and `hashCode()` for your example:

```
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    if (this == other) {
        return true;
    }
    if (null == other
            || this.getClass() != other.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }

    return Double.compare(this.dnum1, ((Test) other).dnum1) == 0;
}

public int hashCode() {
    long bits = Double.doubleToLongBits(this.dnum1);
    return (int) (bits ^ (bits >>> 32));
}
```

#### About floating point arithmetic

Your example shows the disadvantage of `double` usage for floating point calculations - even values with the same magnitude can give close, but different results. Maybe you should use [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)?

Also, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413448/double-vs-bigdecimal) answers.

Comment: Unfortunately, Double.compare( .9 - .1, .7 + .1 ) ) does not test equal; 1 is returned. And doubleToLongBits returns different values for the two expressions.

Comment: That's right, because `(.9 - .1) = 0.8` and `(.7 + .1) =
0.7999999999999999`. And they are not equal, obviously. I think you're trying to solve this problem in a wrong way - maybe you should use [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html), if you need a floating point arithmetic? And, of course, you can later convert it to `double`, if you need, with `doubleValue()`.

Comment: Thank you. BigDecimal would be suitable way to resolve the issue.

Comment: If I'm writing a graphics application I would not want to use BigDecimal and I would still want to treat position (1.0, 1.0) as equal to position (.999999999999999, .99999999999999)

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Double.hashCode(Math.round(dnum1));
}


public boolean equals( Object other )
{
    if(other instanceof Test)
        return equals(test);
    return false;
}
public boolean equals( Test other )
{
    if(other == null)
        return false;
    return isEqual(dnum1,other.dnum1);
}
public boolean isEqual(double number,double anotherNumber){
    if (number == anotherNumber)// eg 0, NaN, +/-INFINITY
        return true;
    return Math.abs(number - anotherNumber) <= EPSILON;
}
```