# BigDecimal how to use?

Tags: java

Lets say ItemImpl takes in   "int ItemId, String name, BigDecimal price"

How do I put a BigDecimal number in the input of this?

```
Item item = new ItemImpl(5, "Hockey Stick", BigDecimal(1.5));
```

Also what's the point of BigDecimal?

Comment: this post can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413448/double-vs-bigdecimal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Item item = new ItemImpl(5, "Hockey Stick", new BigDecimal("1.5"));
```

Best practice is to use a String due to precision issues

And this link I think answers pretty much everything you might want to know:
http://www.opentaps.org/docs/index.php/How_to_Use_Java_BigDecimal:_A_Tutorial

Answer (score 0):

The point of `BigDecimal` is that it offers better precision than `double` and it also solves round-off errors.