# When to use BigDecimal instead of double. Why does below code display this out

Tags: java

When using `BigDecimal` instead of `double` why does line 8 print `0.01` when line 4 prints `0.009999999999999998`?

```
double a = 0.02;
double b = 0.03;
double c = b - a;
System.out.println(c); // line #4 prints 0.009999999999999998
BigDecimal _a = new BigDecimal("0.02");
BigDecimal _b = new BigDecimal("0.03");
BigDecimal _c = _b.subtract(_a);
System.out.println(_c); // line #8 prints 0.01
```

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413448/double-vs-bigdecimal

Comment: what's wrong with 0.009999999999999998?? looks like 0.01 to me :)

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz It matters in financial calculations, stock price analysis, gas price analysis, altitude calculation for aircraft etc. In some other scenarios, it does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me sometime back, when I was working for a financial firm and a difference of 1 cent in calculation made me work for the whole weekend.

It all depends on how floating point numbers (which have two parts mantissa and exponent) are stored in hardware and always have a precision property attached to it.

doubles suffer from the same precision property(specifying how precisely it is represented).

`BigDecimal` is an exact representation of the floating point numbers and does not have `precision`. So, for any financial calculations, BigDecimal is the way to go where a difference of .0001 matters. Having said that, it is slower as compared to using `double`.

You should give a read to `BigDecimal` javadoc, it will be a good read and enlighten you.