# Possible lossy conversion while compiling in Java

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter price: $");
float price = keyboard.nextFloat();
System.out.println("Early payment (Y/N): ");
String char1 = keyboard.nextLine();

float amount = price;

if (char1.equals('Y'))
{
  amount = price * 0.9;
}

System.out.printf("Amount due: $%0.2f\n", amount);


}
}
```

when compiling it gives the error of possible lossy conversion, regardless if i pass an int or float.. what is the issue here?

Comment: The issue is that `0.9` is a `double` literal, not a `float` literal, you should use `0.9f`.

Comment: `char1.equals('Y')` can never be true.

Answer (score 1):

In Java by default every decimal number is considered `double`. You are multiplying a `float` by `double` which result in a `double`:

```
float price = 10.7f;
float result = price * 0.9; //this does not work
```

Here, we have two options. The first one is to convert 0.9 as `float`, putting the `f` in the front of the number:

```
float result = price * 0.9f;
```

The second option is to hold the result as `double`:

```
double result = price * 0.9;
```

Please, use `double/float` only for doing simple tests. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413448/double-vs-bigdecimal) we have a good explanation about the difference between `Double` and `BigDecimal`:

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that `0.9` is a `double`, which causes the value of  `price * 0.9` to be coerced to a `double` as well. To prevent that, you should use `0.9f` to indicate you want a `float` type.

You also have an issue with `char1` actually being a String, not a `char`, so `char1.equals('Y')` will always be `false`.

In addition, your `%0.2f` format says you want to zero-fill your output, but you neglected to specify a minimum width. Something like `%04.2f` should work.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter price: $");
        float price = keyboard.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("Early payment (Y/N): ");
        String str1 = keyboard.next();

        float amount = price;

        if (str1.equals("Y")) {
          amount = price * 0.9f;
        }

        System.out.printf("Amount due: $%04.2f\n", amount);
    }
}
```