# String Huge Decimal Numbers In Java

Tags: java, double

```
double a=816992306.6297043221;
System.out.println("a="+a);
```

The problem with this is that the number is too large for double, and it gives the following output:

```
a=8.169923062970433E7
```

When I decrease the number, the result gets displayed correctly.
What is the efficient solution for this problem?

Comment: The number is not too large for double. It's just shown in the scientific notation. There is nothing wrong with that, it's intended behavior.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Double vs. BigDecimal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413448/double-vs-bigdecimal)

Comment: With the answer by Davide Lorenzo MARINO in mind it is indeed correct though that you are loosing precision on the last 3 decimal places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) number instead of `double`:

> Immutable, **arbitrary-precision** signed decimal numbers.

`BigDecimal` can represent **any number with the choosen precision**.

`Double` has **limits** on maximum and minimum values and **on precision**.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a precision problem.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax

You can check this link out for learning about format.

You can use DecimalFormat Class

```
double d1 = 3.14159;
double d2 = 1.235;

DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("#.##");

double roundedD1 = format.format(d1); // 3.14
double roundedD2 = format.format(d2); // 1.24
```

If you want to set the precision during runtime.

```
format.setMaximumFractionDigits(precision);
```