# Spark decimal type precision loss

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm doing some testing of spark decimal types for currency measures and am seeing some odd precision results when I set the scale and precision as shown below. I want to be sure that I won't have any data loss during calculations but the example below is not reassuring of that. Can anyone tell me why this is happening with spark sql? Currently on version 2.3.0

```
val sql = """select cast(cast(3 as decimal(38,14)) / cast(9 as decimal(38,14)) as decimal(38,14)) val"""
spark.sql(sql).show
```

This returns

```
+----------------+
|             val|
+----------------+
|0.33333300000000|
+----------------+
```

Comment: Your SQL works fine on Spark 2.2.1, producing 0.3333... with 14 `3`s.

Comment: Looks like someone created a JIRA ticket for this with this post referenced. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a current open issue, see [SPARK-27089](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-27089?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel&focusedCommentId=16787374#comment-16787374). The suggested work around is to adjust the setting below. I validated that the SQL statement works as expected with this setting set to false.

```
spark.sql.decimalOperations.allowPrecisionLoss=false
```

Answer (score 2):

Use BigDecimal to avoid precision loss. See [Double vs. BigDecimal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413448/double-vs-bigdecimal)

example:

```
scala> val df = Seq(BigDecimal("0.03"),BigDecimal("8.20"),BigDecimal("0.02")).toDS
df: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[scala.math.BigDecimal] = [value: decimal(38,18)]

scala> df.select($"value").show
+--------------------+
|               value|
+--------------------+
|0.030000000000000000|
|8.200000000000000000|
|0.020000000000000000|
+--------------------+
```

Using BigDecimal:

```
scala> df.select($"value" + BigDecimal("0.1")).show
+-------------------+
|      (value + 0.1)|
+-------------------+
|0.13000000000000000|
|8.30000000000000000|
|0.12000000000000000|
+-------------------+
```

if you don't use BigDecimal, there will be a loss in precision. In this case 0.1 is a double

```
scala> df.select($"value" +  lit(0.1)).show
+-------------------+
|      (value + 0.1)|
+-------------------+
|               0.13|
|  8.299999999999999|
|0.12000000000000001|
+-------------------+
```