# spark decimal issue - automatically round or truncated the 10th decimal

Tags: apache-spark, decimal

I have a decimal issue but different from
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55046492/spark-decimal-type-precision-loss)

I have tried to set spark.sql.decimalOperations.allowPrecisionLoss=false. It can fix some of the issues as mentioned in the above question. However, one of the issues can not be solved. After I switched to spark, the number will automatically truncate or round the 10th decimal. I have included two examples shown below:

- 17749.5500000001 -> 17749.5500000000
- 17154.2099999999 -> 17154.2100000000

Comment: which spark version are you using ? & how are you trying can you post some code if possible ?

Comment: Spark 2.4.2; I run spark sql in aws emr. code:  (a - b) / 100 * c