# Spark: why is Decimal(36, 16) rounding after 6 digits?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I do not understand the below behavior. I am trying to divide `bkg_fx_rate` by `sys_currency`, in order to get FX cross rate. Both the fields are of type Decimal(36, 16). What I would expect with this precision, in the first row, would be 1.5387893576534500/0.9330900000000000 = 1.6491328356894297. Yet, what I get instead is 1.649133. Why is that? I have tried to cast, and change DecimalType() arguments, but it never gives me more than 6 places on the right side.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55046492/spark-decimal-type-precision-loss

Answer (score 2):

Cast them to `DoubleType()`

```
>>> data = [(1.5387893576534500,0.9330900000000000)]
>>> 
>>> schema = StructType([
...     StructField('a', DoubleType(),True),
...     StructField('b', DoubleType(),True)
... ])
>>> 
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data,schema=schema)
>>> df.withColumn('c', df.a/df.b).show()
+----------------+-------+------------------+
|               a|      b|                 c|
+----------------+-------+------------------+
|1.53878935765345|0.93309|1.6491328356894297|
+----------------+-------+------------------+
```