# Rounding down to its nearest decimal? BigDecimal vs Alternate Form

Tags: java

I have the following formula and code:

I tried with Math.Floor, and others but I am not getting the result expected

```
double netPay = grossPay - totalDeduction;

System.out.printf("Net Pay: $%.2f", (netPay));
```

The idea is to get the number as follows:

46.225

Rounded as
**46.22**

and not as 46.23

Comment: Note that really, you should be using BigDecimal, not double.

Comment: @LouisWasserman: The given code does not perform any calculation which cannot be accomplished sufficiently accurate with `double`.

Comment: @goodvibration `float` and `double` are approximate data types.  When dealing with money, approximate is not good enough.

Comment: How could I implement BigDecimal, and rounding that as I expected? @LouisWasserman

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated by commenters: **For financial purposes, use BigDecimal.**

Aside from that:

```
double netPayCents = Math.floor(netPay * 100);
netPay = netPayCents / 100d;
```

**Why use BigDecimal?**

Floating point values(including double values) can be very precise, but they have issues when trying to be absolutely precise. They are always subject to rounding, after most mathematical operations.

See this thread for more detail: [Double vs. BigDecimal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413448/double-vs-bigdecimal)

Comment: The `100d` in the denominator should be optional, i.e. just `/ 100` should work.  But other than that, +1 to what I was about to write.

Comment: the 'd' is indeed optional, but I prefer to avoid implicit convertions, because then I am more sure that a calculation is not accidentally done in integer or long. It's just personal preference. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the below code:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.math.RoundingMode;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double netPay = 46.225;
        DecimalFormat f = new DecimalFormat("##.00");
        f.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN);
        System.out.println(f.format(netPay));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
46.22
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the method I use:

For Example netPay value is **46.225**

By using Below code you will get the output like **46.22**

```
double netPay =46.225;           // just assigning your decimal to a variable
netPay =netPay *100;              // this sets netPay to 4622.5
netPay =Math.floor(netPay);      // this sets netPay to 4622.0
netPay =netPay/100;              // this sets netPay to 46.22
```

Vnstead of above code you can just use below single line it will also work the same

```
netPay =Math.floor(netPay*100) / 100;
```

Happy Coding !!!!!!!!!!!!!!