# Is there a way to sum up Decimal values in java

Tags: java

I've been trying to sum up decimal values using double in java and it doesn't work well, got a wrong answer.

I've already tried with Double, Float, BigDecimal.

```
{
    double a = 2595.00;
    double b = -1760.76;
    double c = -834.00;
    double d = -.24;

    System.out.print(a+b+c+d);
}
```

The expected result should be "0" But Got 9.1038288019262836314737796783447265625E-15

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: *"I've already tried with Double, Float, BigDecimal"* It works with BigDecimal: http://ideone.com/oJU0Nm Perhaps you used the `BigDecimal(double)` constructor? If so, it's really worth reading [the JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#%3Cinit%3E(double)).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder My guess is OP must've used the `BigDecimal(double)` constructor, which gave the wrong value upon addition. This is what I got 9.1038288019262836314737796783447265625E-15

Comment: @AmardeepBhowmick - Yup, see the edit to the comment. :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `BigDecimal` for this purpose and make sure you input the numbers as `String` in the `BigDecimal` constructor:

```
 BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal("2595.00");
 BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal("-1760.76");
 BigDecimal c = new BigDecimal("-834.00");
 BigDecimal d = new BigDecimal("-.24");

 System.out.println(a.add(b).add(c).add(d));
```

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/oJU0Nm)

Output is:

```
0.00
```

From the [Java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal(java.lang.String)) for `BigDecimal(String)`:

> This is generally the preferred way to convert a float or double into
>   a BigDecimal, as it doesn't suffer from the unpredictability of the
>   BigDecimal(double) constructor.

Check this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413448/double-vs-bigdecimal) for why `double` results in a loss of precision.

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed by the previous answers about double precision, the value here is very close to zero. You can see it with `System.out.format` as well.

```
System.out.format("%.14f%n",a+b+c+d);
System.out.format("%1.1f%n",a+b+c+d); //to print 0.0
```

Comment: Your answer prints 0.0 if the sum is 0.02.  Don't do this.