# This prints out SOP.Number@566776ad can't figure out how to make it just print out the value

Tags: java, expression

> This is supposed to have a Processor, Expression, Sum, Number and Product class.
>   Processor execute Expression and expression should execute  Sum and Product maybe even number. I'm not too sure about that.
>
> This goes to Number class  Expression e1 = new Number(2.0);

```
        public Number(double operand) {
        Double code = new Double(operand);
           code.toString();
            System.out.println("double : " + code);
           return;
```

> This passes fine. I get the number

```
public class TestSOP  {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Processor proc = new Processor();
    Expression e1 = new Number(2.0);
    Expression e2 = new Number(3.1);
    Expression e3 = new Number(-5.0);
    Sum s1 = new Sum(e1, e2, e3);
    System.out.println("s1 - " + proc.execute(s1));
    Product p1 = new Product(s1, e3);
    System.out.println("s1 - " + proc.execute(s1));
    // etc.
}
```

}

> The problem is this line  Sum s1 = new Sum(e1, e2, e3); the Sum has a constructor that has to pass the expression. I have tried many different ways after passing the operand to get it into a double but all I get is SOP.Number@566776ad. I'm not sure what to do or try next
>   Bellow is the Sum Class.

```
public  class Sum implements Expression   { 
 public Sum(Expression ...operand ) {
SOP.Number.Numbers(operand); }
```

Comment: `SOP.Number` does **not** override `toString`. Fix that and your problem will go away.

Comment: Are you talking about operand.toString(); because I still get [LSOP.Expression;@6d06d69cs1

Comment: You're printing an object of type 'Numbers'. This class has no toString so therefore it uses Object.toString. Implement a toString method or create a new method which returns the double and prints that. Be aware of calculating with double values, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413448/double-vs-bigdecimal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, System.out.println() calls passed in object's toString() function to convert the object to a string representation, so you don't need to convert it beforehand. Also, if you do so, you would need to assign it to a variable:

```
String printCode = code.toString(); // redundant
System.out.println("double : " + printCode);
```

Double overrides toString() method (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/lang/Double.html), hence your number is printed, while Number only inherits it from Object class (see 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html).

You could write your own class which extends Number class, and override toString() method.