# Output not as expected - Zero Coupon Bond Calculator

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class zeroCouponBond 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner usrObj = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Face Value of Bond: ");
        int faceValue = usrObj.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Years To Maturity: ");
        int yearsToMaturity = usrObj.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Rate of Interest: ");
        int returnOnInvestment = usrObj.nextInt();

        double BP1 = (faceValue/(Math.pow((returnOnInvestment + 1), yearsToMaturity)));

        System.out.println("Present Bond Value: "+BP1);

    }
}
```

Input data 
Face Value - £1000
Years to Maturity - 20
Rate of Interest - 5

Given the formula: F / (1 + r)^t

why do i get 2.73511...
I expect 376.89

Comment: Put those numbers in your formula and that's the exact number that pops out, 2.7351112277912533887121746361168e-13. How are you doing your math?

1000 / ((1+5)^20) = 2.7351112277912533887121746361168e-13

do note the e-13

Comment: The same in excel gives me 376.889...

Comment: Well excel must have a rounding error then, take a look at how a calculator does it.

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1000+%2F+%281%2B5%29%5E20

Comment: incidentally the following test data is the same in both this program and excel - 100000, 4, 10 (6.8301....)

Comment: useful website btw

Comment: The interest rate is a percentage.  Need to adjust for that in your code?

Comment: ok, taking a look...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Divide the percentage by 100 (assuming the users are providing "5" meaning "5%"). And use `doubles` not `ints` to avoid truncation and loss of precision during the calculation.

```
double faceValue = 1_000; //usrObj.nextInt();
double yearsToMaturity = 20; //usrObj.nextInt();
double returnOnInvestment = 5; //usrObj.nextInt();
double BP1 = faceValue / (Math.pow(((returnOnInvestment / 100f) + 1), yearsToMaturity));
```

Also, take a look at `BigDecimal` - for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413448/double-vs-bigdecimal). This is probably more appropriate for your situation (handling money values).

Comment: Thanks, i was messing around for ages and was getting nowhere.  Never would of thought to add this (returnOnInvestment / 100f) to the Math.pow method...