# -= 0.1 strange result

Tags: javascript, floating-point

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is double Multiplication Broken in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420752/is-double-multiplication-broken-in-net)

**JavaScript code:**

```
var n = 1; 
while ( n > 0 )
{
  n -= 0.1;
  document.body.innerHTML += n + "<br/>";
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UpUE6/4/

**I expected:**

```
0.9
0.8
0.7
0.6
0.5
0.4
0.3
0.2
0.1
0
```

**But got this:**

```
0.9
0.8
0.7000000000000001
0.6000000000000001
0.5000000000000001
0.40000000000000013
0.30000000000000016
0.20000000000000015
0.10000000000000014
1.3877787807814457e-16
-0.09999999999999987
```

**Could anyone explain what's going on there?**

Comment: Dupe of so many dupes [Strange loop on Java for 0.1 to 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5400565/) or [Is double multiplication broken in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420752/). See the [gory details](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're seeing an artifact of the way computers do floating-point arithmetic. See, for example, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Machine_precision

Answer (score 11):

From [The Floating-Point Guide](http://floating-point-gui.de/basic/):

> **Why don’t my numbers, like 0.1 + 0.2 add up to a nice round 0.3, and
>   instead I get a weird result like
>   0.30000000000000004?**
>
> Because internally, computers use a
>   format (binary floating-point) that
>   cannot accurately represent a number
>   like 0.1, 0.2 or 0.3 at all.
>
> When the code is compiled or
>   interpreted, your “0.1” is already
>   rounded to the nearest number in that
>   format, which results in a small
>   rounding error even before the
>   calculation happens.

Comment: +1 This should have been the accepted answer (or alternatively mine).

Answer (score 6):

This will solve your problem

http://jsfiddle.net/AVPNx/

```
var n = 1;
while ( n > 0 ){
    n -= 0.1;
    result = n.toFixed(1);
    document.body.innerHTML += result + "<br/>";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're dealing with a floating point number.  Check out the toFixed and toPrecision methods.

Answer (score 1):

Not all numbers can be represented exactly, even if they have a simple representation in decimal notation. This is because JavaScript uses [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) to represent floating point values, and thus uses base 2 instead of base 10. This leads to you not actually subtracting 0.1 (even though your source code says so), but some value close to it.