# How to print the incremented value by 0.1 using c?

Tags: c

I am trying to print the incremented values up to the given number by (0.1). I am getting two inputs x and y and then I am trying to print the values from x to y incremented by 0.1, but i am facing the problem. Below is my code. Thanks in advance.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
float x,y,i;
scanf("%f %f\n",&x,&y);
for(i=x;i<=y;)
 {
  printf("%.1f ",i);
  i=i+0.1;
 }
```

Input: 
9.4 10.2

Output:

> 9.4 9.5 9.6 9.7 9.8 9.9 10.0 10.1

Expected Output:

> 9.4 9.5 9.6 9.7 9.8 9.9 10.0 10.1 10.2

Comment: `10.10000000000000000074623452 + 0.1 > 10.2`

Comment: what should be the correct solution for this?

Comment: Use integers; scale by `10`; divide by `10` when printing: `for (int i = x*10; i <= y*10; i += 1) { printf("%.1f ", i / 10.0); }`

Comment: Rule of thumb with floating point numbers: don't ever compare for equality or less or equal, or higher or equal. Only use `<` and `>`, never `<=`, `>=` or `==`.

Comment: some other duplicates: [Why "for( i = 0.1 ; i != 1.0 ; i += 0.1)" doesn't break at i = 1.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13542220/995714), [Strange loop on Java for 0.1 to 2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5400565/995714), [Condition to check double is an integer not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54750758/995714)...

Comment: @Akashkumar To provide a correct solution you have to specify, what the actual problem is. The root cause of the issue is rounding errors, so an arbitrary precision library like gmp would work. It might be overkill, however.

Comment: @pmg: This question is not a duplicate of [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken), and that question does not explain how to iterate through floating-point values. Please do not promiscuously close floating-point question as a duplicate of that one. **It does not answer most floating-point questions.**

Comment: Noted @EricPostpischil, I'll be more careful

Comment: Upvoting for a question that includes a [mcve], input, desired output and actual output. Thanks!