# Java double vs BigDecimal for latitude/longitude

Tags: java, double, geospatial, latitude-longitude, bigdecimal

When storing latitudes/longitudes which are typically of the format: 44.087585 (i.e. max 2 numbers before the dot and 6dp) do I need to bother with bigdecimals?

Comment: Irrelevant for the question, but longitude values range from -180 to 180, so that's 3 numbers before the dot. And a potential minus sign :P

Answer (score 202, accepted):

Using `double` has enough precision for accurate lat/lon down to inches for 6-7 decimal places.  In aviation, if decimal degrees are used, they typically go to at least 7 decimal places.  In our NASA simulations, lat/lon data are `doubles` while all other attitude and altitude are floats.  In other words, the 6th decimal place for altitude isn't significant while the 6th decimal place for lat/lon is for sub-foot accuracy.  You should not use `float` for lat/lon if you need precision down to sub-feet.

You can play around in Google Earth to see what accuracy you get by placing markers and manipulating the last decimal digit.

Comment: +1 for the good explanation of the decimal point accuracy with respect to logitudes/latitudes.

Answer (score 41):

`double` should be fine for latitudes/longitudes. `BigDecimal` becomes more important once you start manipulating currency or need to have more control over precision.

Comment: Downvoter: Why the down vote? Feel free to leave a comment - it will make you look reasonable.

Answer (score 7):

A `double` has enough precision for storing that. However, when displaying to users, use a format string like `%.6f` so that you don't print garbage digits out.

Answer (score 7):

The worst accuracy of storing as double is about 3 nm.

If you'd like to calculate it in Java:

```
Math.ulp((double) 180) * 60 * 1852

3.1582203519064933E-9
```

As a bonus; the worst accuracy you get from storing in floats is 1.7 meters.

Comment: I just realized that I also need to make pythagoras with the greatest error in the other direction too. So a little bit worse. :)

Answer (score 6):

If you're concerned about precision, you should probably go with `BigDecimal` [for lots of reasons covered in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322749/retain-precision-with-doubles-in-java/322875#322875).  That said, `double` or `float` *should* be just fine to store what you need in terms of being able to satisfy the range of values that you need.

At just six decimal places of precision I don't think `double` or `float` will trip you up,  but if you start aggregating the values in any way, the minor imprecisions can start to add up.

Answer (score 3):

if you want to control nano-robots in their nano-travels using nano-GPS - go for BigDecimal. otherwise - float/double is enough.