# How to get the full fraction value of a division result in java?

Tags: java, drjava

I am new to Java and I am using DrJava IDE for my testing. I have the following division 49700/40000 and it displays 1.0 instead of 1.2425.

> ```
>  double t = 49700/40000;
>  System.out.println(t);
> ```

Is it something I am doing wrong?

Comment: For reference, similar question and answer. [Division of integers in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7220681/260633)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try, this instead:

```
double t = 49700/40000.0;
System.out.println(t);
```

If both operands are integers the result will be an integer which will be truncated, and then it will be cast in to a double. If, instead, one of the operands is a double, the result will be a double.

Comment: Excellent, that was my mistake, I should define the source also as double then I get double result back. Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: @Nair - You should only define the source as a double if it _IS_ a double. Otherwise you can cast when you divide.

Comment: You can also put a d or f after your numeric constant, e.g. 40000f, but I prefer the trailing .0 as used by @dev.

Answer (score 0):

Use float for decimal number computations