# Calculating the average?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a method that calculates the average

`Note` class:

```
private Double moyenneFinale;

@Column(name = "moyenne_finale")
public Double getMoyenneFinale() {
    return this.moyenneFinale;
}

public void setMoyenneFinale(Double moyenneFinale) {
    this.moyenneFinale = moyenneFinale;
}
```

Class calBean

```
private double result;
public double moyenneFinale;
public calNote {
    result=0.0
    result= ((100 * 20)/100)/45;
    moyenneFinale=result;
    note.setMoyenneFinale(moyenneFinale);
}
//getter and setter
```

the result should be 0.44
but recorded in the database given value is 0.0
if I make +1 it will be 1.0

Comment: possible duplicate of [Division of integers in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7220681/division-of-integers-in-java)

Comment: @BackSlash The question may be a duplicate but not exactly of the question you linked since this question adds the nuance of operands being literals and their type being changed by adding a `.0` to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the numeric literals at `((100 * 20)/100)/45` are integers so each operation performs integer arithmetic instead floating pointer arithmetic and finally the result is cast to `double` at the assignation operation.

You should change at least one of your literals to `100.0`, `20.0`, `45.0`, ...

Comment: _You should change your constants to 100.0, 20.0, 45.0_ Not exactly: Changing just one of them will do the trick

Comment: @BackSlash That is true, I'll edit my answer to make it more clear.

Comment: @BackSlash I think that changing all of them is clearer and safer.

Comment: @PabloFranciscoPérezHidalgo Those are called literals, not constants.

Comment: @broncoAbierto Can you elaborate? Why do you think it is safer?

Comment: @BackSlash Because if you were to change the expression and eliminate the one `double` literal, you could forget to change another one of them to keep the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

In line

```
result= ((100 * 20)/100)/45;
```

you are using operator **/** on integers. When used on integers, operator **/** behaves as "**DIV**" (resulting integer). Examples: 10/4=2, but 10.0/4=2.5, 10/4.0=2.5, 10.0/4.0=2.5.

Options are:

To set numbers as 100.0, 20.0, 100.0 and 45.0. (It is enough to set just first one to 100.0).

```
result= ((100.0 * 20)/100)/45;
```

To use casting on numbers. (double)100.

```
result= (((double)100 * 20)/100)/45;
```

Or to add 1.0* before equation;

```
result= 1.0*((100 * 20)/100)/45;
```

Tho, first method is best in your case, second and third are useful if you are given integers x, y, z, t and your result is ((x * y)/z)/t;