# difference in Math.cbrt() and Math.pow()

Tags: java

Why does `Math.cbrt(a)` give a different result than `Math.pow(a, (1/3))`?

```
public class HelloWorld{

 public static void main(String []args){

   int a=8;

   System.out.println(Math.cbrt(a));

   System.out.println(Math.pow(a,(1/3)));
 }
}
```

soln

2.0
1.0

why is there a discrepancy? Is my math wrong or syntax wrong or something that gotta do with pow?

Comment: Integer arithmetic strikes again!

Comment: @user3580294, could you explain!!!

Comment: "please don't rate down" - oops, I missed the "don't" part. Sorry.

Comment: Try `System.out.println(1/3);` Google would help a lot here, too. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7220681/division-of-integers-in-java) is a place to start.

Comment: oops silly me,thanx!!!

Comment: Tip: asking people not to vote down pretty much guarantees someone will do so because they see your request as childish.

Answer (score 3):

```
System.out.println(Math.pow(a,(1.0/3.0)));
```

1/3 will be 0 thanks to integer arithmetic, so you either need to cast to a double, or simply use doubles as shown above, to get the desired result.

Comment: If you're going to use `1.0` or `3.0` the cast is unnecessary. Also, there really isn't much reason nowadays to use `float` -- just use `double`, the extra precision is almost always a good thing.

Comment: Yep, you edited right as I posted my second comment. Good answer now. Some elaboration on what "integer arithmetic" would be nice though.

Answer (score 1):

In Java 1/3 = 0, because you divide integer by integer. If you would use 1/3.0 your result in Math.pow would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

The expression 1/3 is evaluated as an integer division, resulting in 0. Then, pow is called as `pow(8, 0)`, which correctly returns 1. Try writing `pow(a, (1.0 / 3.0))` instead.

Answer (score 0):

One more thing you may take note of is, using cbrt() gives you the exact correct value for the expression whereas using pow() gives you an approximate value to it . You may ever try it by using a= 64, 125 , 216 or 343 for reference. This won't give you an exact round up value for pow() statement and in most case wrong value if you try to print the int value for the same by type-casting.
I hope this answer helps for better clarification.

Comment: The spec requires that `cbrt` is accurate to within 1 ulp *in either direction*. On narrowing, rounding is performed *toward zero*. As far as I can tell, there is no guarantee that it will round "correctly" for large perfect cubes. `cbrt` should probably be *more* accurate than `pow`, but there's no way to make it exact in general.

Comment: Note that `pow` makes similar precision guarantees, so the difference is likely to be extremely small, presumably resulting from the (very slightly) imprecise representation of the exponent.