# Why is answer Zero for division?

Tags: java, math

Within my `Activity` I am attempting to `divide` two values then `multiply` them by 100 in order to give a `percentage score.`

My issue is that the percentage score is always zero, even though this is impossible with the values I am using.

What am I doing wrong?

Declaring the 2 variables at start of activity:

```
int score = 0;
int totalQuestions=0;
```

Onclick logic showing how they are calculated:

```
public void onClick(View v) {

        if (checkForMatch((Button) v)) {
            //increment no of questions answered (for % score)
            totalQuestions++;
            //increment score by 1
            score++;

        } else {
            //increment no of questions answered (for % score)
            totalQuestions++;

        }

    }


public void writeToDatabase() {
        // create instance of databasehelper class
        DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        int divide = (score/ totalQuestions );

        int percentageScore = (divide * 100);

        Log.d("Pertrace", "per score "+ percentageScore);
        Log.d("divide", "divide "+ divide);


        // Adding the new Session to the database
        db.addScore(new Session(sessionID, "Stroop", SignInActivity
                .getUserName(), averageMedLevel, medMax, averageAttLevel,
                attMax, percentageScore, myDate, "false", fileNameRaw, fileNameEEGPower, fileNameMeditation, fileNameAttention));

        // single score, used for passing to next activity
        single = db.getScore(sessionID);

    }
```

Note: from my Trace logs i can see that is it the `int divide` that is zero, why would this be the case considering that `score` and `totalQuestions` are always greater than zero? E.g. 20 and 25.

Comment: Integer division truncates.

Comment: `20/25 = 0.8`. `((int) 0.8) = 0`.

Comment: @NiekHaarman I think that's only half the problem, since 20/25 is already 0.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Division of integers in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7220681/division-of-integers-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is this line

```
int divide = (score/ totalQuestions);
```

You are dividing the numbers and storing in an int.

You need to store in a `double`

```
double divide = (double)score / totalQuestions;
```

If you want the result as int

```
double divide = (double)score / totalQuestions;
int percentageScore = (int) Math.ceil(divide * 100);
```

Comment: That still won't work, since the division will have already been carried out as integer division. You get 0.0.

Comment: @SeanOwen:- Thanks. Removed the brackets!

Comment: Your current solution always returns 100

Comment: @SeanOwen:- I didnt get that. What I missed?

Comment: There are still unnecessary brackets in the next-to-last line, and a space before the division operator in two places would be nice.

Answer (score 2):

You are saving them in `int`. Save values in `float` or `double`.

Also, when division occurs, the intermediate result is saved in one of the variable that is used in division. If that is an int, it will be `truncated` before being saved in `double`. So do something like `double divide = (double)score * totalQuestions`

Comment: That's not all of the problem. Even if the variable it's stored in were `float` or `double` the result of the division was already 0.

Answer (score 1):

You are performing integer division. First cast score to a double (so you get floating point math), then I would use [`Math.round()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round%28double%29) to round the result of the multiplication. For example,

```
int score = 3;
int totalQuestions = 4;
double divide = ((double) score / totalQuestions);
int percentageScore = (int) Math.round(divide * 100);
System.out.println(percentageScore);
```

Output is the expected

```
75
```

Comment: Thank you, how could I add implement an algorithm so that now the total questions answered is also considered, I.e. if u answer 75/100 correct that is a better score than 3/4 as it is more reliable due to a larger sample size?

Comment: @user3968848 Mathematically that's nonsense. Statistically it might be true.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add the fact that it should be a higher score as the game is timed and the user was able to answer 70 questions correct within the time limit as opposed to 7

Answer (score 0):

The operands need to be `float` or `double`, and so does the variable you put it in:

```
double divide = (double) score/ totalQuestions;
```

Comment: thanks, how can I then round the double answer up to the nearest int? Note: the final answer must be an int!

Comment: @user3968848:- Check my answer. I have updated that!

Comment: After multiplying by 100? Use `Math.ceil()`