# Double division behaving wrongly

Tags: java, double

I have a `HashMap` called `List<String, Intger> wordFreqMap` whose `size` is `234`

```
wordFreqMap = {radiology=1, shift=2, mummy=1, empirical=1, awful=1, geoff=1, .......}
```

I want to calculate the `term frequency` of each word.

```
term frequency = frequency of term / total number of terms

public static Map<String, Double> getTFMap (Map<String, Integer> wordFreqMap)
    {
        Map<String, Double> tfMap = new HashMap<String, Double>();
        int noOfTerms = wordFreqMap.size();
        Double tf;

        for (Entry<String, Integer> word : wordFreqMap.entrySet() ) 
        {
                tf = (double) ( word.getValue() / noOfTerms );
                tfMap.put(word.getKey(), tf );
        }
        return tfMap;
    }
```

My problem is that, `tfMap` is returning `{radiology=0.0, shift=0.0, mummy=0.0, empirical=0.0, awful=0.0, geoff=0.0, .....}`

I don't understand why it returns `0.0` for every term. How do I fix it?

I should get something like `{radiology=0.00427, shift=0.00854, ...}`

Comment: A HashMap is not a List.

Comment: The cast to `double` in your code is closing the barn door after the horse has bolted :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Division of integers in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7220681/division-of-integers-in-java)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're performing an integer division and then type casting:

```
tf = (double) ( word.getValue() / noOfTerms );
                ^-----integer division----^
```

Type cast one of the elements in the division to convert into a floating point division:

```
tf = ((double)word.getValue()) / noOfTerms;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are doing integer division and then casting that answer to a double. What you need to do is cast one of the two values to a double first, and then do division on it. That should get you the answer you desire.

Answer (score 1):

`Integer/Integer` is an `Integer` which is casted to a `Double` so ,it remains an `Integer` expanded to a `Double`.

Change it to

```
 tf =  ( (double)word.getValue() / noOfTerms );
```

Answer (score 1):

what you are doing is dividing an integer by another integer and then trying to cast that to a double. int/int is a int do though you cast that to a double you will not get the actual value with decimal points.

```
int/int -> int
```

What you should do is either cast word.getValue() or noOfterms to double
then

```
int/double -> double
double/int -> double
double/double -> double
```

e.g.

```
  tf =  (double)word.getValue()/noOfTerms;
```

or

```
tf =  word.getValue()/(double)noOfTerms;
```