# Using double method into a segment class

Tags: java

How can I write a double slope method for a segment class?

I have two variable: p1 = x1, y1   and p2 = x2, y2.

I did this code but this is wrong:

```
public double slope() {
    return (double)(p2.y - p1.y)/(p1.x-p2.x);
}
```

Can someone tell me why is it wrong?
What is the right way to write it?

Thank you!

Comment: FYI:  code snippets only run when someone uses Javascript.  You're using Java, and that isn't supported.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Division of integers in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7220681/division-of-integers-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the type of `p1`, it could be a `Point` which takes both an x and a y coordinate.

```
public class Point {
    private final int x;
    private final int y;

    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }
}
```

You'd have to use `getX()` and `getY()` to get the X and Y coordinates.  You'd also have to be sure you created the point with `new Point(1, 2)` as well.

Also, be sure that you're getting the right cast behavior by adding parens around it and your numerator:

```
return ((double)(p2.getY() - p1.getY()))/(p1.getX() - p2.getX());
```

(Although that above seems to scream for a `deltaY` and `deltaX` method alone)