# Java Multiplication .*

Tags: java, multiplication

Why is .* used in Java? 
For example

```
double probability = 1.*count/numdata;
```

gives the same output as:

```
double probability = count/numdata;
```

Comment: What type are `cout` and `numdata`?

Comment: Not if `count` and `numdata` are integers.

Comment: they are both integers, what difference does it make?

Comment: Read about integer division.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: [Division of integers in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7220681/division-of-integers-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `count` and `numdata` are integral: `int` or `long` the result again will be integral (**integer division**), so the fractions gets lost; truncated, not even rounded. As a probability is between 0.0 and 1.0, and so numdata >= count, you'll get only 0 or 1.

Simplest would be to make the division floating point:

```
double probability = ((double)count) / numdata;
```

or (more obfuscating though!)

```
double probability = count;
probability /= numdata;
```

Comment: so int can store for example 26.5? isn't int always whole numbers for example 26?

Comment: 53 / 2 = 26, (int) 26.5 == 26. "integer" or the French "entier" means whole number, and you are right: only whole numbers can be stored.