# Java/Pawn Maths formula returns 0

Tags: java, math, formula

could someone explain me what am I doing wrong here, and how can I make this formula to be working? right now it returns 0 in Java and Pawn. But it works in PHP, which isnt making much sense for me.

```
int test = (65 / 65 / (1 + 25) * 10000);
```

Comment: That's because in PHP all the arithmetic is floating-point, and this Java snippet is working with integers.

Comment: I'm not sure what's going wrong, but in Java integer division will truncate the results. Try `(65.0 / 65.0 / (1.0 + 25.0) * 10000.0);` for floats.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Division of integers in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7220681/division-of-integers-in-java)

Comment: Thank you guys, @eigenchris , that's what I've been looking for. Post your Answer so I can mark it as the answer.

Comment: And thanks to all of you! :)

Comment: More well placed parentheses will make it work more like the way you want. Java of course has defined rules as to order of evaluation, but *never* depend on such rules in a language. Force your desired order of evaluation with parentheses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java, integer division will truncate the results. For example, `5/2` will truncate `2.5` to `2`.

To ensure you're using `float` with numeric constants, add a `.0` on the end, as in:

```
int test = (65.0 / 65.0 / (1.0 + 25.0) * 10000.0);
```

Answer (score 2):

Java operations for multiplication and division is left to right, so your expression is really:

```
(((65 / 65) / 26) * 1000)  // Clarifying parenthesis
((1 / 26) * 1000)          
(0 * 1000)                 // integer division!
0
```

To avoid this, you just need to ensure the operations are casted to a double.

The simple way would be just changing the first value to a double, either by:

```
int test = (65D / 65 / (1 + 25) * 10000);
```

Or

```
int test = (65.0 / 65 / (1 + 25) * 10000);
```

However, if you are refactoring your code later, you might want to change more than just the first value.