# Android If Statement Not Evaluating as Expected

Tags: android, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have the following If statement:

```
private boolean NextLevel(int intCorrectAnswers, int intNumberOfQuestionsAsked) {
    if (intNumberOfQuestionsAsked >= 20 && ((intCorrectAnswers / intNumberOfQuestionsAsked) >= .8)){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

What I want is if the number of questions asked is at least 20 and the percentage correct is at least 80% then return true.

Stepping through the code, I am answering at least 46 questions and getting all but 1 correct and it always returns false. What am I missing?

Comment: when you divid integers the result is an integer

Comment: you are missing java's basic - integer math

Comment: Ok thank you. But why did you down vote my question? I thought I asked a valid question.

Comment: Somebody must really hate newcomers here. BTW, your division will result to an integer and will never come out as 0.8. It will always result to 1 since you're dividing two integers.

Comment: Ok got it. Thank you. I am used to programming in VBA, where you can divide 2 integers and the result can be a double. So to solve my issue, I am just going to change everything to a double. Thanks everyone.

Comment: we were all newbies once upon a time... :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Division of integers in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7220681/division-of-integers-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are performing an integer division which will not return a floating or decimal value that is why your result is always false. Cast your variable
to double or float to get your desired result.

```
double dResult = ((double)intCorrectAnswers / (double)intNumberOfQuestionsAsked);
if (intNumberOfQuestionsAsked >= 20 && (dResult >= 0.8)) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```