# Java programming while loop

Tags: java, while-loop

Write a program that always asks the user to enter a number. When the user enters the negative number -1, the program must stop requesting the user to enter a number. The program must then calculate the average of the numbers entered exclusive of the -1. Make use of the while loop repetition structure to implement the program.

This is my solution, but the problem is that I cant exclude the negative number from the sum. Please help

```
Import javax.swing.*;
public class whileloop
{
    public static void main (String [] args ) 

    {
       int i =0, tot = 0;
       int count = 0;
       double avg = 0.0;
       while(i != -1) 
       {
           i = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter a number");
           if(i != -1)
           {
              tot += i; 
              count++;
              avg = sum/count;
              System.out.println("Sum: " + sum + "\t\t" + "Average: " + avg); 
           }
       }
       System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you don't store `-1`, you don't have to care

Comment: Is this your original code? `sum` is not declared, did you mean `tot` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    Import javax.swing.*;
    public class whileloop
    {
        public static void main (String [] args )



       {
           int i =0, tot = 0;
           int count = 0;
           double avg = 0.0;
           while(true) 
           {
           i = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter a number");
           if(i != -1)
           {
              tot += i; 
              count++;

           }else{
            avg = tot/count;
              System.out.println("Sum: " + tot+ "\t\t" + "Average: " + avg);
break;
         }
       }
       System.out.println();
    } }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Import javax.swing.*;
public class whileloop{
  public static void main (String [] args ) {
    int i =0, tot = 0;
    int count = 0;
    double avg = 0.0;
    while(i >= 0){
      i = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter a number");
      if(i >= 0){
        tot += i; 
        count++;
      }
   }
   avg = sum/count;
   System.out.println("Sum: " + sum + "\t\t" + "Average: " + avg); 
}
```

in short:

```
while ( bigger then 0){
  read number
  check if positive number{
    add number tot total for the average
  }
}
calculate average
print average result
```

You do also want the average calculation to be outside the while-loop for better readable code.

Answer (score 0):

First, why are you using a JOptionPane and making your life harder? There is no need to use a JOptionPane for a simple assignment such as this. Second, the calculation for the average should be outside the while loop. If you keep it inside, you risk the program throwing a runtime exception due to calculation problems. Here is what your code should look like from the while loop to the println statement. I cleaned up your code so it's more streamlined.

```
while (i > 0) {
    tot += i;
    count++;
}

int average = tot / count;
System.out.println("Sum: " + sum + "\t\t" + "Average: " + avg);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is logically correct, i.e., it satisfies your requirements.

The only problems that I see are:

1. You print the sum and avg at every iteration (not necessary).
2. You should cast the sum to double, when calculating the avg (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7220681/division-of-integers-in-java)).
3. You should use `tot` instead of the undefined `sum` (as Gyro Gearless commented).

Thus, my suggested solution (assuming that you need the graphics) is:

```
Import javax.swing.*;
public class whileloop
{
  public static void main (String [] args ) 

  {
   int i =0, tot = 0;
   int count = 0;
   double avg = 0.0;
   while(i != -1) 
   {
       i = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter a number");
       if(i != -1)
       {
          tot += i; 
          count++;              
       }
   }
   avg = (double)tot/count;
   System.out.println("Sum: " + tot + "\t\t" + "Average: " + avg); 
  }
}
```