# Average Score Java using a Do While loop

Tags: java

I am working on an assignment for school to compute the average test score from given inputs. It does not exit the do/while loop when I type in *"-1"*. The count does not increment when I plug in a value and as such the average does not calculate correctly.

> 1. Create a class called Average.
> 2. Try to use separate sections in the main method to declare all variables, get input, do processing, and perform output. Create a comment for each section.
> 3. In the declarations section of main, declare an double variable called average.
> 4. In the input section of main, display an opening message using JOptionPane that explains the purpose of the program.
> 5. In the processing section of main, assign the value of average by calling a method named calcAverage().
> 6. Within the calcAverage method, declare int variables count, score, and total, and a double variable called average.
> 7. Also in the calcAverage method, use a do-while loop to get scores from the user until the user enters -1 to quit. (Your message to the user should be, "Enter a score or -1 to quit".)
> 8. In the calcAverage method, calculate the average score and return that value to the main method.
> 9. In the output section of main, display a JOptionPane window that states (for example), "The average of the 5 scores is 75.8."

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Average {
    static int count = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Declaration section
        double average;
        //Input Section
        calcAverage();
        //Processing Section
        average = calcAverage();
        //Output Section
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The average of the " + count + "scores is" + average);
    } // end main

    public static double calcAverage() {
        int count = 0, score = 0, total = 0;
        double average;
        String input;
        do {
            input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a score or -1 to quit");
            score = Integer.parseInt(input);
            total = total + score;
            count++;
        } while (score != -1);
        average = (total / count);
        return average;
    } // end calcAverage
} // end class
```

Comment: You're getting zero as the average, aren't you? If so, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7220681/division-of-integers-in-java

Comment: You are calling `calcAverage()` twice in your `main` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `count` local variable in `calcAverage` is shadowing the `count` variable you declared `static` in the `Average` class, so the `static` variable is never updated; it remains 0.  Don't re-declare this variable in `calcAverage`.

You are calling `calcAverage` twice, and ignoring what is is returning the first time.  Because of this, you have to enter `-1` twice to finish the program.  Remove the first `calcAverage` call.

You always count the number, even if `-1` is entered, because the condition isn't checked until the end of the loop.  Add an `if` condition to update `total` and `count` only if `score` isn't `-1`.

You have integer division on this line:

```
average = (total / count);
```

In Java, division of integers yields an integer, so the average of 2 numbers 5 and 6 would be 5, not 5.5.  [Cast one of them to `double`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7220681/division-of-integers-in-java).

```
average = ((double) total / count);
```

Comment: As the asker of this question, you may, at your discretion, [accept exactly one answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) that you think helps you the best.