# Temperature Java Program

Tags: java

I am trying to get code that implements a textual view and a graphical view of the conversion using the MVC pattern. Currently, my code converts temperature from Fahrenheit to Celsius.

I think I have to use the Observable class and Observer interface in the Java standard library for the MVC pattern implementation, but I could be wrong.

This is what i got so far.

```
public class Temperature {
 public static String CUnit = " °C";
 private double tempF;
 private double tempC;
 public Temperature() {
 tempF=0;
 }
 public Temperature(double tempF) {
 this.setTempF(tempF);
 }
 public double getTempF() {
 return tempF;
 }
 public void setTempF(double tempF) {
 this.tempF = tempF;
 }
 private void convertFtoC(){
 tempC = (getTempF()-32) * 5/9;
 }
 public double getTempC() {
 convertFtoC();
 return tempC;
 }
 public void setTempC(double tempC) {
 this.tempC = tempC;
 }
}
```

Also here is my class MVC[image]

Am I close? Any help is appreciated

Thank you

Comment: + functionName(params) :<type> is the same as public <type> functionName(params), your getter musn't call any function.

Comment: Beware the confounding results of integer division in this line: `(getTempF()-32) * 5/9;` You may want to cast these as doubles. For more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7220681/division-of-integers-in-java

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't make the "convert" a publicly exposed function.  Have them set Celsius or Fahrenheit, and in the "setter" code calculate the values for both (and store them in member variables)

Answer (score 1):

You have a decent MVC class diagram, but your code doesn't match your class diagram.

For example, in your class diagram, Temperature is a subclass of Observable, but in your code, it is not a subclass of Observable.  Also, from this side of the internet, it is not clear if you even have an observable class.