# Why does my code return 1 always?

Tags: java, math

```
    double formula1, formula2;
    int plus;
    int VALUE = 10000;    



  private void processFormula2()
    {
        for (int k = 0; k <= VALUE; k++) {
            if (k % 2 != 0) {
                if (plus % 2 == 0) {
                    double math = 1/k;
                    formula2 += math;
                    System.out.println("Getting Formula: "+ formula2);
                    plus++;
                } else {
                    formula2 -= 1/k;
                    plus++;
                }
               // System.out.println("Term: " + formula2);
            }
        }

    }
```

I am trying to get my formula to print out the result of Pi based off this formula that my teacher gave us. But for some reason it just returns 1.0, not really sure why. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated :)

Comment: There are many variables which are unknown for us like `VALUE`, `plus`, `formula2` .. Please provide all relevant parts of code ..

Comment: Te expand on what hagrawal said...  Please [edit] your post to provide us a [mcve].  Without that, we're even more in the dark than you are.

Comment: What is the value of 'VALUE'? Where is your 'plus' variable declared? Where is your 'formula2' variable declared? Are you aware that you should be using mixed division (1.0 / k) instead of integer division for the declaration of 'math' (you can alternatively cast 1 to a double)?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add this I apologize :/

Comment: Suggestion: put more println statements in and see what it is doing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Division of integers in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7220681/division-of-integers-in-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the problem:

```
double math = 1/k;
```

and

```
formula2 -= 1/k;
```

`k` is an `int` variable, so the JVM won't never return a decimal number in this statement. It will take only two possible values: 0 (if k > 1) or 1 (if k == 1) because the JVM performs the division **before** promoting the result to `double`.

Try this:

```
formula2 -= 1/(double)k;
```

Take a look at [Numeric Promotions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, there are multiple errors with variable declaration.

`double math = 1/k;`will not truly work in Java due to how integer division is handled. You must either cast '1' to a double like `double math = (double)1/k;` or specify that you are using mixed mode arithmetic by using `double math = 1.0/k;`. This is also a problem for your `formula2` variable (Along with you should always initialize your variables like `formula1`, `formula2`, and `plus`). You must also do the same thing with `formula2 -= 1/k;`.

Secondly, we have no idea what you are setting those variables to in the first place, nor do we have any test cases to compare to.