# error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int

Tags: java

```
public class FoodItem {

 private String name;
 private int calories;
 private int fatGrams;
 private int caloriesFromFat;

 public FoodItem(String n, int cal, int fat) {
    name = n;
    calories = cal;
    fatGrams = fat;  
 }

 public void setName(String n) {
    name = n;
 }

 public void setCalories(int cal) {
    calories = cal; 
 }

 public void setFatGrams(int fat) {
    fatGrams = fat;  
 }

 public String getName() {
    return name;
 }

 public int getCalories() {
    return calories;
 }

 public int getFatGrams() {
    return fatGrams; 
 }

 public int getCaloriesFromFat() {
    return (fatGrams * 9.0); 
 }

 public int getPercentFat() {
    return (caloriesFromFat / calories);
 }

 // Ignore for now
 public String toString() {
    return name + calories + fatGrams;
 }
}
```

My instructions are to "Include a method named caloriesFromFat which returns an integer with the number of calories that fat contributes to the total calories (fat grams * 9.0).", but when I try to compile I get the above error. I have no clue what I have wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've used a `double` literal `9.0` in your multiplication in `getCaloriesFromFat`.  Because of this, `fatGrams` is promoted to a `double` for the multiplication, and the product is a `double`.  However, you have that method returning an `int`.

You can use an `int` literal (`9`, no decimal point) or you can have `getCaloriesFromFat` return a `double` instead of an `int`.  Since you're just multiplying by `9`, I would use the `int` literal `9`.

Comment: Also, my driver calls for the percent of fat "System.out.printf("The percent of fat is %.1f%%\n", fries.percentFat());" but when I run the driver it just returns 0.0%. Do you have any idea what is causing this?

Comment: [Division of integers in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7220681/division-of-integers-in-java).