# Java: Please explain this code in detail for me.

Tags: java, arrays

this question is related to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35810542/5888956

Basically, I have to write a program that reads in the integer from the keyboard, and it has to be able to display 50! using only array. (cannot use Biginteger or anything)
I got this so far, thanks to the help from the previous post.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Factorial
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int n;

        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter n");
        n = kb.nextInt();
        int [] result = fact(n);

        int i = result.length-1;
        while (i > 0 && result[i] == 0)
        {
            i--; 
        }

        System.out.print(n + "! = ");
        while (i >= 0)
        {
            System.out.print(result[i--]);
        }

        System.out.println();
    }

    public static int[] fact(int n)
    {

        int[] a = new int[100];
        a[0] = 1;



        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            int carry = 0;
            for(int j = 0; j < a.length; j++)
            {
                int x = a[j] * i + carry;
                a[j] = x % 10;
                carry = x / 10;             
            }

        }

        return a;
    }
}
```

But I can't still understand the logic behind here. 
Especially, this part,

```
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
{
      int carry = 0;
      for(int j = 0; j < a.length; j++)
      {
           int x = a[j] * i + carry;
           a[j] = x % 10;
           carry = x / 10;             
      }
}
```

I'm trying to solve this with pen and paper, so that I can understand it completely. (of course with the small number like 4!)
So if I type 4 for n, 4! is 24 (4*3*2*1). 
In my logic, when `i` is `1` `a[0]` is `1` because I initialized above, but after the for loop ends once, does it become `0`?

```
i = 1, j = 0
x = a[0] * 1 + 0 = 1
a[0] = 0
carry = 1
// ------repeat the loop
i = 2, j = 0
x = a[0] * 1 + 1 = 1
a[0] = 0
carry = 1
```

So it is apparently not the right logic, I think.
Can someone please please help me to understand this?

Comment: why do you even need an array? You can use an int right? And 50 factorial would just be a number.

Comment: @RahulSharma No you can't because an `int` can only hold 32-bits numbers. So the largest number an `int` can represent is a measly 2.8 billion or so

Comment: @Maljam largest number of `int` is `pow(2,31) - 1` and it is apploximately 2.1 billion, not 2.8

Comment: @MikeCAT oops, thanks for the correction. It's even measlier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The factorial operation just means multiplying a whole bunch of numbers, so conceptually, it is not a difficult operation to implement. The reason why it quickly becomes a problem when implementing in code, is that it produces huge numbers, in fact, too large to be held in one `int` (4 bytes) or even `long` (8 bytes) variables (`12!` is the max you could hold in an `int`). Otherwise, we would just do something like:

```
int fact = 1;
for(int i = 2 ; i <= n ; i++) {
    fact *= i;
}
```

So one way to deal with this is to treat a number as an "array of digits", in base 10. For example, the number `2016` could be treated like this array: `int[] digits = {2, 0, 1, 6}`, which is just another way of saying `2016 = 2*1000 + 0*100 + 1*10 + 6*1`.

Now let's imagine that we have 8-bits computers, and we can't represent numbers larger than `255` (or `pow(2,8)-1`). We wouldn't be able to simply do `2016*2` directly, but, because multiplication is distributive `a(b+c) = ab+ac`, we could decompose the multiplication of the "large" number `2016` into smaller multiplications like so:
`2016 → {2, 0, 1, 6} → 2*1000 + 0*100 + 1*10 + 6`
`2016 * 2 = (2*1000 + 0 + 1*10 + 6) * 2 = (2*2)*1000 + (2*0) + (2*1)*10 + (2*6)`

Now we can do these small multiplications like you would by hand:
`2016 * 2 → {2, 0, 1, 6} * 2 → {2*2, 0*2, 1*2, 6*2} → {4, 0, 2, 12}`

We get `12` for the first digit, so we need the carry over the `1`:
`{4, 0, 2, 12} → {4, 0, 2+1, 2} → {4, 0, 3, 2} = 4032`

That's exactly what your code does:

```
a[0] = 1;
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    int carry = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
        int x = a[j] * i + carry;
        a[j] = x % 10;
        carry = x / 10;             
    }
}
```

It takes your number or "array of digits" `a`, and multiplies the digits `a[j]` individually by `i` → `x = a[j] * i`. If it's bigger than 9, take the extra to carry it to the next digit → `carry = x / 10`, and you're left with the remnant as the value of the digit → `a[j] = x % 10`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I totally get it now.