# Java/Android: Why does multiplying with a fraction equal 0?

Tags: java, android, math, brackets, fractions

I have come upon this problem.

I am working in android and I am trying to calculate a int value.

I can use this code:

```
int newCenterY = getHeight() * 3 / 5;
```

and it will work fine.

However, if I use this code:

```
int newCenterY = (3 / 5) * getHeight();
```

then android studio will warn me with: *(3 / 5) * getHeight(); can be replaced with 0*  and it will indeed result in 0.

Are those two pieces of code not the same thing?

Comment: There's no fraction type in Java. That is integer division.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7220681/division-of-integers-in-java

Comment: `float centerY = (3.0 / 5) * getHeight();`

Comment: Your division lead to integer. Which is less than 0 so its will rounded to zero.  An integer can't be in double (fraction). As @Sotirios said.