# Math floor mixing types error?

Tags: java

I have this:

```
String a = tonsescolhidos.getValue().toString();
int tons = Integer.parseInt(a);        
float distlevel = 256/(tons - 1);       
int temp; 
temp =  Math.floor(((float) (tons / distlevel) + 0.5)*distlevel); 
tons = temp;
```

I get the error: "Incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int" in the 5th line. How do i cast the variables in the right way.. what am I missing?

Comment: `float distlevel = 256/(tons - 1);` is also wrong: [Division of integers in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7220681)

Comment: If you want the float value of your division, @Tom is right. You may do `256f / (tons - 1)` instead. The ensures that 256 is a float, which in turn makes the division a float division. If `tons` is 1, you will get a division by 0 error, of course.

Answer (score 2):

`Math.floor` only has one overload: [`double Math.floor(double)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#floor(double)). That always returns a double.

You would need to explicitly cast it to an `int`:

```
temp = (int) Math.floor(...);
```

But note that it is potentially lossy: `double` can store values too large to store in an `int`. So, you need to ensure that it's not a lossy operation by ensuring that the `double`'s value is between `Integer.MIN_VALUE` and `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, by constraining the inputs appropriately.

Alternatively, rearrange your calculation so that you can do it all in integer math.