# getting the wrong meal cost

Tags: java, types, java.util.scanner

**
**

Given the meal price (base cost of a meal), tip percent (the percentage of the meal price being added as tip), and tax percent (the percentage of the meal price being added as tax) for a meal, find and print the meal's total cost.

Here is my code

```
public class Solution3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        double mealCost = scan.nextDouble(); // original meal price
        int tipPercent = scan.nextInt(); // tip percentage
        int taxPercent = scan.nextInt(); // tax percentage
        double tip = mealCost *(tipPercent/100);
        double tax = mealCost*(taxPercent/100);
        double total= mealCost+tip+tax;
        // cast the result of the rounding operation to an int and save it as totalCost 
        int totalCost = (int) Math.round(total);

         System.out.println("The total meal cost is "+totalCost+" dollars");
    }
}
```

Expected Output

```
The total meal cost is 15 dollars.
```

My Output

```
The total meal cost is 12 dollars.
```

Please help me out.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You're doing integer division, which truncates decimals. Try `/100.0` instead.

Comment: Thanks man it worked .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Division of integers in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7220681/division-of-integers-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculate answer as:

```
double tip=(mealCost*tipPercent)/100;
double tax=(mealCost*taxPercent)/100;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's an integer division issue.

Try this:

```
double tip = mealCost *(tipPercent/100.0);
double tax = mealCost*(taxPercent/100.0);
```

Comment: that's perfect!