# Check if string contains a character with for loop?

Tags: java, string, for-loop, char

I am currently working on a simple code that will check if an user inputted String contains character(s) that are specified in the for loop.

My current code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class AutumnLeaves {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int G = 0;
    int R = 0;
    int Y = 0;
    int B = 0;
    String S = sc.nextLine();
    for (int i = 0; i < S.length(); i++) {
        if (S.contains("G")) {
            G++;
        } else {
            if (S.contains("R")) {
                R++;
            } else {
                if (S.contains("Y")) {
                    Y++;
                } else {
                    if (S.contains("B")) {
                        B++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    int total = G + R + Y + B;
    System.out.println(G/total);
    System.out.println(R/total);
    System.out.println(Y/total);
    System.out.println(B/total);
}
```

}

As you can see, it checks if the string contains such characters and it will increase the counter of the character by one. However when I run it, I don't receive the results I predicted.
If I input GGRY, it outputs 1 0 0 0. When the desired out put is

`0.5
0.25
0.25
0.0`

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Total should equal 4.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Division of integers in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7220681/division-of-integers-in-java)

Comment: The total works but I'm having trouble with the division part.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `S.contains` returns true if the whole string contains the given character. `S.charAt` should solve your problem:

```
for (int i = 0; i < S.length(); i++) {
    if (S.charAt(i) == 'G') G++;
    else if (S.charAt(i) == 'R') R++;
    else if (S.charAt(i) == 'Y') Y++;
    else if (S.charAt(i) == 'B') B++;
}
```

Also, dividing integers will return an integer (rounded down). As such your output would always be `0` unless all the characters are the same. Just cast them to `double` before printing:

```
System.out.println((double) G/total);
System.out.println((double) R/total);
System.out.println((double) Y/total);
System.out.println((double) B/total);
```

Edit: As pointed out by Sumit Gulati in a comment, a switch statement will have better performance in Java 7. Also, as David Conrad pointed out using only `if`s in the `for` loop would work too as the conditions are mutually exclusive.

Comment: (The `else`'s aren't strictly needed, since the conditions are mutually exclusive.)

Comment: If you are using Java 7, use switch case. It has better performance.

Comment: I am currently using IntelliJ Idea with Java8, but will definitely use switch case if I some how change to 7, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your earlier code `S.contains("some character")` was finding the index of the character in the entire string. Use `S.charAt(i)` to specifically find the index at `i`th location in the string. 
Finally, you need to convert the integer to floating point in order to print output as floating values.

```
public class AutumnLeaves {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int G = 0;
        int R = 0;
        int Y = 0;
        int B = 0;
        String S = sc.nextLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < S.length(); i++) {
            if (S.charAt(i) == 'G') {
                G++;
            } else {
                if (S.charAt(i) == 'R') {
                    R++;
                } else {
                    if (S.charAt(i) == 'Y') {
                        Y++;
                    } else {
                        if (S.charAt(i) == 'B') {
                            B++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        int total = G + R + Y + B;
        System.out.println(G * 1.0 / total);
        System.out.println(R * 1.0 / total);
        System.out.println(Y * 1.0 / total);
        System.out.println(B * 1.0 / total);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Why does multiplying the variable by 1.0 work? When I multiply it by 1 I get a totally different result.

Comment: Multiplying by 1.0 which is of type double automatically converts the expression to type double. So 5/2 = 2 if not double. However, 5.0/2 = 2.5 since it is now a double :)

Comment: Ah that's cool! So when I multiply it by 1 the compiler is actually rounding it to the nearest whole number because it's an integer. I reckon adding (double) would work too  as stated by Leon.

Comment: I have upvoted the answer but I need 15 reputation for it to be visible! Sorry about that

Comment: That's no problem Glace. I appreciate that.