# The total score always equals 0.0 no matter what input of num1, num2 or num3

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

What is wrong with this quote? It always outputs 0.0 instead of the total score result

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class d {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int num1;
        int num2;
        int num3;
        int percentnum1;
        int percentnum2;
        int percentnum3;
        double totalscore;

        System.out.print("Enter paper 1 score (out of 90): ");
        num1 = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter paper 2 score (out of 90): ");
        num2 = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter IA score (out of 20): ");
        num3 = input.nextInt();

        percentnum1 = (num1 / 90) * 100;
        percentnum2 = (num2 / 90) * 100;
        percentnum3 = (num3 / 20) * 80;

        totalscore = (percentnum1 * 0.4) + (percentnum2 * 0.4) + (percentnum3 * 0.2);

        System.out.println("The total score is " + totalscore);


    }
}
```

Comment: javascript !== java

Comment: Welcome to SO. Change `numX` as well as `percentnumX` to double to avoid rounding to 0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Division of integers in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7220681/division-of-integers-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

seems like the code below is causing the problem:

```
percentnum1 = (num1 / 90) * 100;
percentnum2 = (num2 / 90) * 100;
percentnum3 = (num3 / 20) * 80;
```

if **all** of `num1`, `num2` and `num3` are values less than its denominators the result (`totalscore`) will be `0.0` because of integer division, even if some of the variables were `90/90` or `20/20` and others were less than it's denominators, you would again get the incorrect result and again due to integer division (though this time not necessarily `0.0`).

The solution is to simply, use `double` types to keep the precision.

```
double num1;
double num2;
double num3
double percentnum1;
double percentnum2;
double percentnum3;
double totalscore;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `int` to `double` [to avoid rounding down to 0](http://www.browxy.com/SubmittedCode/820470).

Answer (score 0):

If you like to use `int` types, you can multiply the number first. Hope it is helpful.

```
percentnum1 = num1 * 100 / 90;
percentnum2 = num2 * 90 / 100;
percentnum3 = num3 * 80 / 20;
```