# What is the difference between Truncated Division and Floored division?

Tags: java, division

I need theoretical answer using mathematical approach. Is there any mathematical difference between them and how do they make impact in programming languages.

Comment: Depends on your notion of *Glorified Subtraction*. What do you mean by it ?

Comment: @ChandlerBing As multiplying is just glorified addition as `5*5` is just `5+5+5+5+5`, similarly division is just glorified subtraction. `12/3` is `12-3=9(1) 9-3=6(2) 6-3=3(3) 3-3=0(4)` and thus ***4*** is our answer.

Comment: Whoever simplifies multiplication as *glorified addition* is not considering negative numbers. E.g. if `3 * 7 = 7 + 7 + 7`, then what is `-3 * 7`? You can't add `7` with itself `-3` times. Same goes for simplification of division as *glorified subtraction*. So, stop trying to simplify. Or if you insist, extract the negative sign first, they apply again after. --- Also, the question title is supposed to be a *summary* of the question text, not an entirely different question.

Comment: As for `1/2=0.5`, yes there is such an operator in Java. It's `/` (division) of floating-point numbers. You just have to encourage it to not be integer math, but floating-point math, by making at least one of the operands a floating-point number, e.g. `1.0/2=0.5`, `1/2d=0.5`, `1/(float)2=0.5`, etc. See "[Division of integers in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7220681/5221149)".

Comment: @Andreas Please check the main question now. And I wanted to know how does any programming language result in `5/-3 = -1`. And if it is dependent on any of these division methods.

Comment: @SparshSinghal "Any" programming language result in `5/-3 = -1` by defining that the language should do so. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44271386/5221149).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to Java terminology, the question of "Truncated Division" vs "Floored division" is best answered by the javadoc of [`RoundingMode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html):

> [**DOWN**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html#DOWN)
> Rounding mode to **round towards zero**. Never increments the digit prior to a discarded fraction (i.e., **truncates**). Note that this rounding mode never increases the magnitude of the calculated value.
>
> [**FLOOR**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html#FLOOR)
> Rounding mode to **round towards negative infinity**. If the result is positive, behave as for `RoundingMode.DOWN`; if negative, behave as for `RoundingMode.UP`. Note that this rounding mode never increases the calculated value.

The Java division operator is defined by JLS [§15.17.2. Division Operator `/`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.2):

> Integer division rounds toward 0.

That is why `5 / -3` result in `-1`.

---

You can also look at the definition of "Truncate" vs "Floor" on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Rounding_to_integer):

> There are many ways of rounding a number `y` to an integer `q` The most common ones are:
>
> - *round down* (or take the ***floor***, or ***round towards minus infinity***): `q` is the largest integer that does not exceed `y`.
> - *round up* (or take the *ceiling*, or *round towards plus infinity*): `q` is the smallest integer that is not less than `y`.
> - **round towards zero** (or **truncate**, or *round away from infinity*): `q` is the integer part of `y`, without its fraction digits.
> - *round away from zero* (or *round towards infinity*): if `y` is an integer, `q` is `y`; else `q` is the integer that is closest to 0 and is such that `y` is between 0 and `q`.
> - *round to nearest*: `q` is the integer that is closest to `y` (see below for tie-breaking rules).

As you can see, Java and Wikipedia agrees on this definition:

- **Truncate:** Round towards zero
- **Floor:** Round towards minus/negative infinity

Note that Java and Wikipedia disagrees on what **Round Down** means.

Answer (score -1):

You're dividing integers, so the result is going to be rounded to the nearest integer. Use floating point variables instead.

For example, the second part of your question, 1.0/2.0 = 0.5.

Comment: You should rephrase the first part of your answer. The result is not rounded, otherwise 2/3 would be 1. It is rounded down when positive, and rounded up when negative. So it is round towards 0.

Comment: The question has been closed with a duplicate flag that doesn't even answer the actual question in the title, so I'll add add some info here: Read the JavaDoc of `Math.floorDiv()`. It explains that floored division always rounds down after dividing, while truncated division (the normal `/` operator) always rounds towards 0 (i.e. cuts off everything behind the decimal point),